# Ubuntu takes one whole minute to boot

Tags: boot, performance

I have a Lenovo G580 with 4 GB DDR-3 RAM and i5 3rd gen processor. I installed Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS and it takes about a minute to boot.

Is it a problem for me?

If yes, how can I solve it? Is it booting slowly with respect to my hardware? My laptop is 7 yrs old and has a traditional HDD.

I ran `systemd-analyze` command and got following output -

```
Startup finished in 4.627s (kernel) + 1min 5.376s (userspace) = 1min 10.003s
graphical.target reached after 1min 5.257s in userspace
```

Comment: Which kind of hard disk do you have? A tradional HDD or a SDD? If it is a HDD, one minute is more or less what I would expect .

Comment: You can change some settings: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187117/slow-boot-boot-19-10-tried-almost-everything & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018576/what-does-networkmanager-wait-online-service-do & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/800479/ubuntu-16-04-slow-boot-apt-daily-service
 I do uninstall all snaps and install .debs for any app I want. There are some that need or want snap apps. Too old for fwupd, so uninstall it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058052/how-to-remove-fwupd-service-from-boot

Comment: @oldfred I want to thank you for your comment I did change the settings my boot is a little bit fast from before but as Zanna stated in her answer I have old hardware which take more time . I can safely blame them.

Comment: Glad your doubt was cleared :) BTW it's Greenonline's answer - I only edited it a bit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is it a problem for me?" - only you can answer that. Do you mind waiting a minute? One of my laptops (DDR2 era) takes over two minutes to load.

As Lorenz Keel stated in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1268946/ubuntu-takes-one-whole-minute-to-boot#comment2148495_1268946), get an SSD if you want a faster boot.

I'd, personally, just max out the RAM, if you can (up to 8GB or beyond). You'll get much better performance (post-boot) with more RAM as it will need to access the slow disk less. Upgrading the RAM will also be cheaper than buying an SSD.

If you have the cash, do both (max RAM and SSD).