# Is it possible to make Ubuntu 20.04 boot faster?

Tags: boot

I'm sorry if my question is rather newbie, because it is - but I've never bothered to tweak my Linux much. I've managed to get my Manjaro (not without some external help) cut boot time to 8-10s (by systemd-analyze) and I'd like to maybe try the same thing with Ubuntu but I am not sure what should I do and if it is possible. By all means it is not extremely slow but there is a major drawback on my nvme SSD since I've been using Manjaro which was up and ready in 10s and now it takes about 25s to get ready with Ubuntu. While the Manjaro was slow because of the grub timeout, Ubuntu has grub set to 0 by default - that one I've checked.

Here's my `systemd-analyze` and `systemd-analyze blame` - if anything else is needed I'll provide it:

```
systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 8.390s (firmware) + 4.976s (loader) + 2.131s (kernel) + 9.071s (userspace) = 24.570s 
graphical.target reached after 9.039s in userspace

systemd-analyze blame
7.076s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                   
5.821s plymouth-quit-wait.service                           
5.041s bolt.service                                         
1.753s grub-common.service                                  
1.727s apport.service                                       
1.159s snapd.service                                        
1.047s systemd-logind.service                               
1.032s networkd-dispatcher.service                          
 996ms accounts-daemon.service                              
 824ms udisks2.service                                      
 595ms polkit.service                                       
 590ms avahi-daemon.service                                 
 563ms bluetooth.service                                    
 539ms NetworkManager.service                               
 438ms switcheroo-control.service                           
 395ms dev-nvme0n1p2.device                                 
 365ms ModemManager.service                                 
 328ms thermald.service                                     
 314ms gdm.service                                          
 311ms wpa_supplicant.service                               
 300ms upower.service                                       
 253ms grub-initrd-fallback.service                         
 242ms e2scrub_reap.service                                 
 240ms gpu-manager.service                                  
 224ms rsyslog.service                                      
 224ms dev-loop1.device                                     
 223ms dev-loop0.device                                     
 184ms snap-snap\x2dstore-467.mount                         
 183ms snap-snapd-8542.mount                                
 182ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1506.mount              
 173ms user@1000.service                                    
 170ms dev-loop2.device                                     
 154ms pppd-dns.service                                     
 128ms systemd-resolved.service                             
 127ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service  
 119ms alsa-restore.service                                 
 118ms systemd-timesyncd.service                            
 106ms dev-loop4.device                                     
 104ms systemd-user-sessions.service                        
 103ms swapfile.swap                                        
 101ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-36.mount
```

(...)

And here's systemd-analyze critical-chain:

```
graphical.target @9.039s
└─multi-user.target @9.039s
  └─kerneloops.service @8.974s +63ms
    └─network-online.target @8.969s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1.891s +7.076s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1.340s +539ms
          └─dbus.service @1.311s
            └─basic.target @1.232s
              └─sockets.target @1.232s
                └─snapd.socket @1.226s +5ms
                  └─sysinit.target @1.210s
                    └─systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service @1.082s +127ms
                      └─system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice @921ms
                        └─system.slice @433ms
                          └─-.slice @433ms
```

Comment: Off the top of my head, I think what you can sensibly tweak is the userspace part, and here NetworkManager takes the longest time with 7 seconds. Maybe setting a static IP can help?

Answer (score 8):

I am using a NVMe SSD to boot. And have 20.04 Kubuntu installed. I also change grub to 3 sec delay from default of 10 sec, just to have time to press a key if needed.

```
fred@z170-focal-k:~$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 2.667s (kernel) + 5.167s (userspace) = 7.834s 
graphical.target reached after 5.155s in userspace
```

Turned off NetworkManager-wait with systemctl:

```
systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=282437

Changed from quiet splash to noplymouth, will see boot process rather than Ubuntu logo. Sometimes you then can see what process is hanging system, also. Even though not using raid nor encryption, installing drivers supposedly helps.

```
sed -i '/GRUB_TIMEOUT=/ s/10/3/' /etc/default/grub
sed -i '/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT/ s/"quiet splash"/"noplymouth"/' /etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub
sudo apt install libblockdev-crypto2 libblockdev-mdraid2,
```

turned off printer when rebooting,

removed all snaps, prefer .debs for most apps

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd
```

If UEFI firmware update not supported (yet) and no thunderbolt, one of my systems also does not have bluetooth, so I also uninstall that on that system only

```
sudo apt-get purge fwupd
systemctl status bolt
boltctl list
systemctl mask bolt.service
sudo apt-get autoremove blueman bluez-utils bluez bluetooth
```

Many with slow boot issues have reinstalled an have a reference in fstab to a bad UUID. Best to confirm all UUIDs are correct.

```
lsblk -o name,fstype,size,label,mountpoint,uuid | egrep -v "^loop"
cat /etc/fstab
```

Only if swap partition & reformatted this could be wrong UUID.

```
 cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
```

Be sure to mount partitions with noatime.

```
UUID=54029c4f-0cbe-413e-80ce-78a4995b0551 /   ext4 noatime,errors=remount-ro  0  1
```

More details:

[slow boot boot 19.10 (tried almost everything)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187117/slow-boot-boot-19-10-tried-almost-everything)

[What does NetworkManager-wait-online.service do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018576/what-does-networkmanager-wait-online-service-do)

[Ubuntu 16.04 slow boot (apt-daily.service)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800479/ubuntu-16-04-slow-boot-apt-daily-service)

[How to remove fwupd.service from boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058052/how-to-remove-fwupd-service-from-boot)

[Do I really need apt-daily.service and apt-daily-upgrade.service?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038923/do-i-really-need-apt-daily-service-and-apt-daily-upgrade-service)

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2436900&p=13932499#post13932499

[Ubuntu 15.04 network manager causing slow boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615006/ubuntu-15-04-network-manager-causing-slow-boot)

Comment: I did everything you did - besides disabling bluetooth (I'm using it actually) and it cut down from about 25s to 19s - it's still far from desirable. Now there is a gpu-manager.service that takes up nearly 3s but there are many services like dev-nvme02n1p2.device, backlight:intel_backlight.service, rfkill, upower,network-dispatcher and so on that even though each one of them takes up from 650ms to about 200ms - combining them it cause a long boot in the end. Userspace and kernel times are similar to yours but adding firmware and loader to it then it's about 12 or 13 additional seconds.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and SSD firmware. While not your specific issues, that can improve how hardware is seen. I am also now using Kubuntu which for whatever reason seems a bit faster.

Comment: For those who are using Ubuntu 22.04, note that removing `snapd` will uninstall Livepatch and Firefox

Comment: You can still install Firefox .deb with ppa., if using 22.04 or later You also have to reset priorities as shown or it will reinstall the Firefox snap.
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04