# Ubuntu 20.04.1 slow to boot and sometimes fails

Tags: boot, 20.04

Ubuntu 20.04.1 on my HP Pavilion dv6-3050us laptop is very slow to boot and sometimes boot fails completely so that I have to power down and power up again, at which point it works.  This is a sole boot installation - there is not other OS on the computer.  I use a traditional hard drive, not an SSD.  Can anyone suggest please what is going wrong and how this can be fixed, please?  The output from systemd-analyze blame is:

```
25.539s plymouth-quit-wait.service                     
24.702s dev-sda1.device                                
16.928s snapd.service                                  
11.131s networkd-dispatcher.service                    
10.033s dev-loop15.device                              
 9.974s accounts-daemon.service                        
 9.421s dev-loop13.device                              
 9.272s dev-loop0.device                               
 9.269s dev-loop11.device                              
 9.268s dev-loop10.device                              
 9.259s dev-loop12.device                              
 9.259s dev-loop9.device                               
 9.259s dev-loop8.device                               
 9.256s dev-loop14.device                              
 9.200s dev-loop18.device                              
 9.192s dev-loop16.device                              
 9.179s dev-loop17.device                              
 9.069s dev-loop19.device                              
 9.020s dev-loop7.device                               
 8.364s udisks2.service                                
 7.580s fwupd.service                                  
 7.235s dev-loop1.device                               
 7.229s dev-loop5.device
```

Comment: Are you using snaps (the loop devices), I prefer .deb anyway so first thing I remove. Other things to try/check: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster/1284332#1284332

Comment: Thanks, Oldfred.  Would you please tell me how I shift from snaps to .deb?  Might it be snaps that sometimes cause the Ubuntu boot to fail?  Or is this something else?

Comment: Snaps should not cause boot to fail, just make it slower. Link shows how to remove all snaps. #list snaps to see if you want .deb version of anything
`sudo snap list` I use synaptic to search for apps that I want to install. Software center is not clear that it will install a snap or not.

Answer (score 0):

could you try don't use snaps? because the Ubuntu system mounts a virtual disk for snap installed every time it boots, this should make linux boot faster

If you enabled some services that can fail sometimes, try to disable then and enable manually when you need it

Comment: Thanks CanalPC.  But how would I find out which services might be failing?

Comment: that should appear while boot, in the splash screen press the right arrow key and see, if a service fail, should appear with [ FAILED  ] service and not with [ OK ]