# Dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 is taking 3x longer than Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I am running a dual boot with ubuntu on a seperate SSD and Windows on another SSD. It's taking far longer to boot up ubuntu that it should be. I tried changing my grub settings to skip the menu and boot right into Ubuntu which didn't make much of a difference.

My ubuntu boot loader is installed on the EFI partition on the Windows disk instead of a partition on the Ubuntu disk which I've read is fine but I'm wondering if that might be the issue.

The results from systemd-analyze are:

```
startup finished in 11.993s (firmware) + 4.860s (loader) + 8.598s (kernel) + 9.461s (userspace) = 34.913s 
graphical.target reached after 9.451s in userspace
```

system-analyze blame gets me:

```
6.513s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                   
4.246s plymouth-quit-wait.service                           
1.504s windscribe-cli.service                               
1.189s fwupd.service                                        
1.121s gpu-manager.service                                  
1.063s dev-sda1.device                                      
 842ms systemd-rfkill.service                               
 834ms colord.service                                       
 752ms dev-loop9.device                                     
 734ms dev-loop8.device                                     
 721ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1474.mount              
 720ms snap-opera-98.mount                                  
 693ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-145.mount              
 691ms dev-loop11.device                                    
 646ms dev-loop2.device                                     
 634ms dev-loop17.device                                    
 629ms dev-loop15.device                                    
 626ms dev-loop16.device                                    
 626ms dev-loop3.device                                     
 626ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service  
 625ms dev-loop10.device                                    
 612ms dev-loop18.device                                    
 609ms dev-loop14.device                                    
 596ms dev-loop1.device                                     
 594ms snap-snap\x2dstore-481.mount                         
 592ms dev-loop12.device                                    
 585ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-128.mount              
 579ms dev-loop13.device                                    
 577ms dev-loop4.device                                     
 573ms snapd.service                                        
 543ms dev-loop5.device                                     
 520ms dev-loop6.device
```

Windows will boot in 8 seconds so I'm not sure why the firmware + loader + kernel are so long for ubuntu.

Comment: Some things to review. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster/1284332#1284332 But firmware being so long is unusual. What brand/model system? You may need UEFI settings. I turn off some so it does not try to look for network boot, I do keep fast boot off. My Skylake system is 9.5 sec for firmware. And you realize Windows is not that fast as it uses fast start up or cache for booting.

Comment: If you check, Windows in not fully shutting down, You can use suspend in Ubuntu to get a similar effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your motherboard's firmware to the latest version. This should be routine maintenance but most people neglect it.

On my work desktop, doing this took nearly 3 minutes off my start up time.

Comment: I have tried that and there were no updates available.

Comment: That's a pity. Well, it sounds like a lot more troubleshooting is in order. Have you disabled Win10 Fast Boot? Ideally, disable hibernation completely: open an admin command prompt and type `powercfg /h off`. You also look to have a lot of Snap apps -- each one creates a loop device. If you don't need them, or there are native packages, remove them all & then disable Snap support. I have done this on my headless Ubuntu Server RasPi4 & it gave a small improvement in startup time.

Comment: So I have fast boot turned off in windows so I can access the drive in ubuntu if needed. I can remove the snaps like opera and discord but I'm not sure if/how I can remove the snap-gnome packages, are those not part of the desktop interface? I don't have any other snap packages so not sure why there are so many loopback devices.

Comment: Do either of these help? Sorry, I do not run the GNOME version of Ubuntu myself.

[1] https://cialu.net/how-to-disable-and-remove-completely-snaps-in-ubuntu-linux/

[2] https://techwiser.com/remove-snap-ubuntu/

Comment: So it looks like I'll need to keep the gnome snaps if I want the default gnome apps to run but removing a few did free up some space and shave a bit off the boot time. Thanks for the help.