# Slow Ubuntu 20.04 Boot on Dual Boot with Linux Mint 18.3 - Help Please!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

Slow Ubuntu 20.04 boot (GRUB setup boots Mint 18.3 and Ubuntu.

```
Linux Mint 18.3  >systemd-analyze:
Startup finished in 5.46s (kernel) + 6.952s (userspace) = 12.416s

Ubuntu 20.04  >systemd-analyze:
Startup finished in 2.322s (kernel) + 1min 35.188s (userspace) = 
1min 37.511s graphical.target reached after 1min 35.146s in userspace

>systemd-analyze blame
  4.243s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                              
  1.260s dev-sdb4.device                                                         
  889ms dev-loop9.device                                                        
  866ms dev-loop8.device                                                        
  789ms dev-loop11.device                                                       
  752ms dev-loop10.device                                                       
  742ms dev-loop12.device                                                       
  699ms snapd.service       
  ...

 So since I read it is NOT plymouth-quit-wait.service itself that
 is the problem, but the things it is waiting on here is that report.
 Now what?
```

---

```
 >systemctl list-dependencies plymouth-quit-wait.service
   plymouth-quit-wait.service
    ● ├─system.slice
    ● └─sysinit.target
    ●   ├─apparmor.service
    ●   ├─dev-hugepages.mount
    ●   ├─dev-mqueue.mount
    ●   ├─keyboard-setup.service
    ●   ├─kmod-static-nodes.service
    ●   ├─plymouth-read-write.service
    ●   ├─plymouth-start.service
    ●   ├─proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount
    ●   ├─setvtrgb.service
    ●   ├─sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
    ●   ├─sys-kernel-config.mount
    ●   ├─sys-kernel-debug.mount
    ●   ├─sys-kernel-tracing.mount
    ●   ├─systemd-ask-password-console.path
    ●   ├─systemd-binfmt.service
    ●   ├─systemd-boot-system-token.service
    ●   ├─systemd-hwdb-update.service
    ●   ├─systemd-journal-flush.service
    ●   ├─systemd-journald.service
    ●   ├─systemd-machine-id-commit.service
    ●   ├─systemd-modules-load.service
    ●   ├─systemd-pstore.service
    ●   ├─systemd-random-seed.service
    ●   ├─systemd-sysctl.service
    ●   ├─systemd-sysusers.service
    ●   ├─systemd-timesyncd.service
    ●   ├─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
    ●   ├─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
    ●   ├─systemd-udev-trigger.service
    ●   ├─systemd-udevd.service
    ●   ├─systemd-update-utmp.service
    ●   ├─cryptsetup.target
    ●   ├─local-fs.target
    ●   │ ├─-.mount
    ●   │ ├─home-bigubuntu-data.mount
    ●   │ ├─systemd-fsck-root.service
    ●   │ └─systemd-remount-fs.service
    ●   └─swap.target
    ●     ├─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-
            5753820a\x2d8370\x2d4f29\x2d86f6\x2ddc56e5ba92a0.swap
    ●     └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-
            82172d10\x2d5331\x2d42a1\x2d8434\x2d15455d6d1ae3.swap



Since I believe this might be related to my partitioning of the two 
Solid State Hard drives, here is the Gparted 0.25.0 report:

Disk#2  250 G SSD  (Mint & Ubuntu live here)
```

---

```
ATA Samsung SSD 850
Size: 232.89 GiB,
Path: /dev/sdb,
Partion table: msdos,
Heads: 255,
Sectors/track: 63,
Cylinders 30401,
Total sectors: 488397168,
Sector size: 512
```

---

```
 Partition:   /dev/sdb3
 File Sys:    fat32
 Mount point: (none)
 Label:       GRUB
 Size:        1.00 GiB
 Used:        2.02 MiB
 Unused:      1021.98 MiB
 Flags:       (none)
```

---

```
 Partition:   /dev/sdb1
 File Sys:    ext4
 Mount point: /
 Label:       (none)
 Size:        128.00 GiB
 Used:        27.65 GiB
 Unused:      100.35 GiB
 Flags:       (none)
```

---

```
 Partition:   /dev/sdb4
 File Sys:    ext4
 Mount point: (none)
 Label:       Ubuntu
 Size:        96.50 GiB
 Used:        47.76 GiB
 Unused:      51.19 GiB
 Flags:       boot
```

---

```
 Partition:   unallocated
 File Sys:    unallocated
 Mount point: (none)
 Label:       (none)
 Size:        1.36 MiB
 Used:        (none)
 Unused:      (none)
 Flags:       (none)
```

---

```
 Partition:   /dev/sdb2
 File Sys:    extended
 Mount point: (none)
 Label:       (none)
 Size:        6.94 GiB
 Used:        (none)
 Unused:      (none)
 Flags:       (none)
```

---

```
 Partition:   /dev/sdb5
 File Sys:    linux-swap
 Mount point: (none)
 Label:       (none)
 Size:        6.94 GiB
 Used:        0 B
 Unused:      6.94 GiB
 Flags:       (none)
```

---

---

```
 Disk#1 - 1T SSD  (data disk for both distros mirrored on DropBox)
```

---

```
 ATA Samsung SSD 860
 Size: 931.51 GiB, 
 Path: /sda
 Partition table: gpt
 Heads: 255
 Sectors/track: 63
 Cylinders: 121601
 Total sectors: 1953525168
 Sector size: 512,  Name: data
```

---

```
 Partition:   /dev/sda1
 Name:        data
 File Sys:    ext4
 Mount point: /home/big/data
 Label:       1T-SSB
 Size:        931.51 GiB
 Used:        28.85 GiB
 Unused:      902.66 GiB
 Flags:       (none)
```

Comment: More info: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster  I believe Mint does not use Snaps, which I uninstall first thing in Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you clean up the post, and post some more info relevant to the problem.

Comment: New to forum and learning how to format stuff here is painful!  If there is a way to upload files, images and stuff would make this a lot easier!  So please guide me into better ways ...

Comment: OK, mikewhatever and company, I have posted more info.  I don't have an issue with snaps, but something is causing this 2 min + 37+ second ubuntu boot.   Tell, me what to run and I will, but I need HELP interpreting this stuff!

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is how I "fixed" that slow Ubuntu boot problem:

I wiped my OS drive off.  Then I reinstalled Mint 18.3 from an
ISO image on USB drive.  Then made and Ubuntu 20.04 ISO image on another USB drive and installed it - by simply choosing install along side Mint.  (BTW, seemed I had to take my 1T SSD drive out to get where this would not "mess" with it!)

Now everything is good.  However, when I put the 1TB drive back in it somehow got installed under /media.  This is where my Dropbox local files live.  I had to got into Disks to make sure it got mounted at boot-up time.  Used GParted a lot in the process.