# Ubuntu 20.04 long boot time

Tags: boot, 20.04, boot-time

I update my ubuntu recenly to 20.04. now it takes a long time to boot.
I have I5 CPU and 8G RAM.

Here the cmd  `systemd-analyze blame`   output:

```
1min 30.094s nmbd.service                                                             
     47.725s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                               
     22.834s udisks2.service                                                          
     22.771s networkd-dispatcher.service                                              
     19.079s snapd.service                                                            
     16.775s dev-sda6.device                                                          
     16.618s accounts-daemon.service                                                  
     15.567s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                                       
     11.738s polkit.service                                                           
     11.591s avahi-daemon.service                                                     
     11.590s bluetooth.service                                                        
     11.498s NetworkManager.service                                                   
     10.792s switcheroo-control.service                                               
     10.786s thermald.service                                                         
     10.782s systemd-logind.service                                                   
     10.780s wpa_supplicant.service                                                   
      9.671s ModemManager.service                                                     
      7.797s dev-loop0.device                                                         
      7.371s dev-loop1.device                                                         
      6.890s dev-loop2.device                                                         
      6.884s fwupd.service                                                            
      6.669s dev-loop4.device                                                         
      5.474s systemd-journal-flush.service                                            
      5.311s dev-loop3.device                                                         
      5.240s bolt.service                                                             
      4.621s systemd-resolved.service                                                 
      4.481s ufw.service                                                              
      3.997s rsyslog.service                                                          
      3.761s apport.service                                                           
      3.673s gpu-manager.service                                                      
      3.362s systemd-udevd.service                                                    
      3.018s grub-common.service                                                      
      2.985s e2scrub_reap.service                                                     
      2.829s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                                           
      2.615s gdm.service                                                              
      2.605s grub-initrd-fallback.service                                             
      2.412s networking.service                                                       
      2.334s apparmor.service                                                         
      1.970s secureboot-db.service                                                    
      1.919s lm-sensors.service                                                       
      1.549s snapd.seeded.service                                                     
      1.427s virtualbox.service                                                       
      1.419s dictd.service                                                            
      1.388s systemd-sysusers.service                                                 
      1.360s keyboard-setup.service                                                   
      1.333s systemd-modules-load.service                                             
      1.328s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-CEF1\x2d926B.service                    
      1.314s colord.service                                                           
      1.221s ccpd.service                                                             
      1.004s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                                       
       997ms systemd-random-seed.service                                              
       888ms systemd-sysctl.service                                                   
       794ms modprobe@drm.service                                                     
       789ms smbd.service                                                             
       770ms snapd.apparmor.service                                                   
       755ms binfmt-support.service                                                   
       646ms upower.service                                                           
       639ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service                      
       633ms systemd-rfkill.service                                                   
       580ms winbind.service                                                          
       542ms snap-core18-1932.mount                                                   
       516ms pppd-dns.service                                                         
       412ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                                             
       407ms systemd-timedated.service                                                
       384ms snap-snap\x2dstore-481.mount                                             
       351ms kerneloops.service                                                       
       335ms ifupdown-pre.service                                                     
       275ms systemd-timesyncd.service                                                
       274ms rc-local.service                                                         
       231ms kmod-static-nodes.service                                                
       218ms console-setup.service                                                    
       217ms user@1000.service                                                        
       213ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-60.mount                                   
       200ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1506.mount                                  
       200ms systemd-remount-fs.service                                               
       200ms systemd-journald.service                                                 
       195ms openvpn.service                                                          
       182ms dev-hugepages.mount                                                      
       182ms dev-mqueue.mount                                                         
       180ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                                                   
       180ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                                                 
       156ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0dddf165\x2d43ec\x2d452e\x2d9e15\x2da64e2699cdfa.swap
       153ms snap-snapd-9721.mount                                                    
       141ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount                                            
       139ms plymouth-start.service                                                   
       133ms systemd-user-sessions.service                                            
       126ms setvtrgb.service                                                         
       117ms dns-clean.service                                                        
       116ms systemd-update-utmp.service                                              
       110ms boot-efi.mount                                                           
       106ms rtkit-daemon.service                                                     
        69ms hddtemp.service                                                          
        67ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                                           
        55ms plymouth-read-write.service                                              
        49ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service                                            
        45ms resolvconf-pull-resolved.service                                         
        41ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service                                     
        16ms alsa-restore.service                                                     
         4ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                                            
         3ms sys-kernel-config.mount                                                  
         1ms snapd.socket
```

and systemd-analyze critical-chain output

```
    graphical.target @2min 25.659s
    └─multi-user.target @2min 25.658s
      └─smbd.service @2min 24.867s +789ms
        └─winbind.service @2min 24.280s +580ms
          └─network.target @38.518s
            └─NetworkManager.service @27.019s +11.498s
              └─dbus.service @27.013s
                └─basic.target @26.670s
                  └─sockets.target @26.670s
                    └─snapd.socket @26.668s +1ms
                      └─sysinit.target @26.291s
                        └─systemd-timesyncd.service @26.015s +275ms
                          └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @23.107s +2.829s
                            └─local-fs.target @22.985s
                              └─boot-efi.mount @22.875s +110ms
                                └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-CEF1\x2d926B.service @21.528s +1.328s
                                  └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-CEF1\x2d926B.device @21.526s
```

Here [systemd-analyze plot](https://ibb.co/xS25Bx9) result.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Personally, I get rid of a lot of that stuff. [Here is a guide](https://askmeaboutlinux.com/2019/11/28/how-to-speed-up-boot-time-on-linux-if-it-boots-slowly/) that's more or less what I typically do. Use it at your own risk and know exactly what each command is going to do before you press the enter key. It should be mostly safe/harmless, but back up your important stuff just in case. Not mentioned there is snap, which I also remove. Some folks like them, so that's up to you.

Comment: Some more details & suggestions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Answer (score 4):

- Evaluate if you can remove sda drive, if not, evaluate what is loaded from sda6 and migrate it on a faster storage.
- Evaluate if you can uninstall/remove your snaps packages.
- Evaluate if you really need virtualbox to start at boot
- **Check your nmdb settings, if the machine is not hosting smb shares, connecting to smb shares, not part of a Microsoft Active Directory, consider uninstalling nmdb and purging its configuration in case you reinstall it in the future.**
- Check your WiFi drivers and WiFi configuration
- **Check your network connection while booting, as your machine is waiting for it.**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like 2 specific events are slowing it down:

1. it is waiting for the network connection to become available
2. it is waiting for winbind/nmbd to do something, possible get a list of all host names on your network

Removing winbind/nmbd or disabling those services should speed it up significantly.

The network wait time seems to be 11s out of your huge delay, but as long as you are not automounting smb or nfs, or are using LDAP for login, you can skip that, and save the 11s