# Very Long booting time after upgrading to 20.04

Tags: boot, upgrade, 20.04

After upgrading my Lenovo ubuntu 16.04 --> 18.04 --> 20.04, most annoying issue is the booting time almost (2 min ~ 2 min 20 sec) starting by clicking the power on, till it is fully ready to be used, on the following manner:

- Till the Ubuntu logo and loading sign shows up: around 45 seconds!!
- Since logo and loading till the login box: around 50 seconds
- After login till desktop shows up: around 20 seconds

I know this is a very common issue on 20.04, but all solutions i found either doesn't match my case or didn't work with me specially deactivate unnecessary services, swap partition UUID double check ..etc.

I can't install it from scratch due to the installed environment and data i have, that it is very hard and a lot of time to re-configure and re-install again.

```
root@Lenovo-G580:~# systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 5.929s (kernel) + 1min 6.508s (userspace) = 1min 12.438s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 5.880s in userspace

root@Lenovo-G580:~# systemd-analyze blame 
29.707s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                               
19.960s dev-sda1.device                                                          
18.337s systemd-journal-flush.service                                            
14.221s udisks2.service                                                          
13.322s networkd-dispatcher.service                                              
12.024s accounts-daemon.service                                                  
 8.895s dev-loop2.device                                                         
 8.710s dev-loop1.device                                                         
 8.707s dev-loop3.device                                                         
 8.684s avahi-daemon.service                                                     
 8.493s dev-loop4.device                                                         
 8.439s polkit.service                                                           
 8.420s dev-loop0.device                                                         
 8.327s NetworkManager.service                                                   
 8.150s switcheroo-control.service                                               
 8.131s thermald.service                                                         
 8.129s systemd-logind.service                                                   
 8.126s wpa_supplicant.service                                                   
 7.004s systemd-udevd.service                                                    
 5.232s ModemManager.service                                                     
 4.695s apport.service                                                           
 4.685s gpu-manager.service                                                      
 4.582s grub-common.service                                                      
 4.015s e2scrub_reap.service                                                     
 3.856s rsyslog.service                                                          
 3.463s apparmor.service                                                         
 3.270s ssh.service                                                              
 1.959s networking.service                                                       
 1.696s lm-sensors.service                                                       
 1.674s grub-initrd-fallback.service                                             
 1.519s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                                           
 1.416s keyboard-setup.service                                                   
 1.411s apache-htcacheclean.service                                              
 1.342s systemd-modules-load.service                                             
 1.309s snapd.apparmor.service                                                   
 1.300s systemd-resolved.service                                                 
 1.102s systemd-sysusers.service                                                 

root@Lenovo-G580:~# systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 5.880s
└─multi-user.target @1min 5.880s
  └─ModemManager.service @35.995s +5.232s
    └─polkit.service @27.542s +8.439s
      └─basic.target @26.902s
        └─sockets.target @26.902s
          └─uuidd.socket @26.902s
            └─sysinit.target @26.756s
              └─systemd-timesyncd.service @26.303s +452ms
                └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @24.738s +1.519s
                  └─systemd-journal-flush.service @6.400s +18.337s
                    └─systemd-remount-fs.service @5.992s +173ms
                      └─systemd-journald.socket @5.627s
                        └─-.mount @5.624s
                          └─system.slice @5.624s
                            └─-.slice @5.624s
```

My HW specs:

```
RAM: 8 GB
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3120M CPU @ 2.50GHz
```

Help please?

Comment: Do you use loops? If not uninstall them. Have you tried everything in this? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Comment: Yes it only affected the first part (grub booting before the Ubuntu logo) decreased to 30 sec!!, thanks to `noplymouth` showed one of possible reasons `ata3: EH pending after 5 tries, giving up` not sure how to fix it. Other parts no matter what i do, disabling services like ModemManager, snap, network wait ....etc, nothing reflecting on the loading time till i manage to login, around 1min 15 sec +/- 10 sec.  So total time is now around 1 min 45 sec. The loops they were default snaps installed not sure if it is safe to remove (core, gtk..., gnomre,...etc), i already disabled snap totally.

Comment: Didn't mention, my drive not SSD "yet", i know it is a big factor, but could it affect that much long time?!

Answer (score 0):

Look at your name services switch file and make sure your network settings are correct.  You may have a setting that is timing out.

Name service switch (/etc/nsswitch.conf), may be set differently.
Other things to check (network, subnet mask, default router) in network settings.
I dont know what 'Modem Manager' is that looks like it is pulling 35 seconds, perhaps it should be disabled instead of timing out, but I dont know your configuration.

Slowness is sometimes hard to troubleshoot, but name service switch and /etc/hosts are used for lookups, so if you are experiencing time outs, that might be an area to start looking.

Comment: I just disabled the network wait service, it reflected a little, not that much. I didn't made changes to nsswitch or hosts files just as default. The Modem Manager used for my 4G modem connection, not using it so i removed it, didn't matter as well, now it says 30 seconds for ssh, which wasn't listed before!