# Ubuntu Boot time is approximately 2 min 30 sec against Win10 is ~10 sec in Dell G3 3500

Tags: dual-boot

My Laptop is Dell G3 3500 with i5 10th Gen with 120Hz display. Ram is 8 GB with 256GB SSD + 1TB HDD memory. B*oot time for pre-installed Windows 10 Home (in SSD) is ~ 10 seconds.* `I dual boot my laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Release LTS (in HDD) and` `bootime is 4sec (kernel) + 2min 24sec (userspace)`.

**How do I reduce the boot time?** I'm not sure how to configure. Kindly guide.

**The terminal outputs are as follows:**

```
ankur@ankur-G3-3500:~$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @2min 23.008s
└─multi-user.target @2min 23.007s
  └─php7.4-fpm.service @1min 43.177s +15.531s
    └─network.target @1min 43.168s
      └─NetworkManager.service @1min 35.788s +7.379s
        └─dbus.service @1min 35.785s
          └─basic.target @1min 35.580s
            └─sockets.target @1min 35.580s
              └─snapd.socket @1min 35.579s +591us
                └─sysinit.target @1min 35.147s
                  └─systemd-timesyncd.service @1min 34.975s +171ms
                    └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @1min 32.819s +1.901s
                      └─systemd-journal-flush.service @3.054s +19.738s
                        └─systemd-journald.service @2.708s +344ms
                          └─systemd-journald.socket @2.705s
                            └─-.mount @2.703s
                              └─system.slice @2.703s
                                └─-.slice @2.703s
ankur@ankur-G3-3500:~$ systemd-analyze 
Startup finished in 3.688s (kernel) + 2min 23.534s (userspace) = 2min 27.222s 
graphical.target reached after 2min 23.008s in userspace
ankur@ankur-G3-3500:~$ journalctl --disk-usage
Archived and active journals take up 4.0G in the file system.
ankur@ankur-G3-3500:~$ journalctl -b --unit systemd-journald
-- Logs begin at Tue 2020-12-15 18:31:38 IST, end at Tue 2021-01-12 17:01:18 IST. --
ankur-G3-3500 systemd-journald[312]: Journal started
ankur-G3-3500 systemd-journald[312]: Runtime Journal (/run/log/journal/09b452451b264a75a304b6a00a2c4733) is 8.0M, max 77.5M, 69.5M free.
ankur-G3-3500 systemd-journald[312]: Time spent on flushing to /var/log/journal/09b452451b264a75a304b6a00a2c4733 is 13.611366s for 934 entries.
ankur-G3-3500 systemd-journald[312]: System Journal (/var/log/journal/09b452451b264a75a304b6a00a2c4733) is 4.0G, max 4.0G, 0B free.
```

**Also, the terminal output for `systemd-analyze blame` is as follows:**

```
ankur@ankur-G3-3500:~$ systemd-analyze blame
36.940s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                                               
21.963s php7.4-fpm.service                                                                       
20.975s snapd.service                                                                            
17.905s systemd-journal-flush.service                                                            
16.579s networkd-dispatcher.service                                                              
14.735s dev-sda4.device                                                                          
13.926s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                                                       
13.925s udisks2.service                                                                          
10.719s apport-autoreport.service                                                                
10.663s accounts-daemon.service                                                                  
 9.820s snapd.seeded.service                                                                     
 9.080s NetworkManager.service                                                                   
 8.595s polkit.service                                                                           
 7.795s bluetooth.service                                                                        
 7.795s avahi-daemon.service                                                                     
 7.697s dev-loop10.device                                                                        
 7.291s fwupd.service                                                                            
 7.250s dev-loop9.device                                                                         
 7.185s smartmontools.service                                                                    
 7.145s dev-loop14.device                                                                        
 7.012s switcheroo-control.service                                                               
 6.971s thermald.service                                                                         
 6.969s wpa_supplicant.service                                                                   
 6.963s systemd-logind.service                                                                   
 6.925s dev-loop12.device                                                                        
 6.515s dev-loop17.device                                                                        
 6.466s dev-loop19.device                                                                        
 6.437s dev-loop5.device                                                                         
 6.029s dev-loop2.device                                                                         
 5.860s gdm.service                                                                              
 5.849s dev-loop0.device                                                                         
 5.816s dev-loop7.device                                                                         
 5.801s dev-loop13.device                                                                        
 5.435s dev-loop16.device                                                                        
 5.391s bolt.service                                                                             
 5.323s ModemManager.service                                                                     
 5.179s dev-loop11.device                                                                        
 5.013s dev-loop4.device                                                                         
 4.949s dev-loop15.device                                                                        
 4.910s dev-loop6.device                                                                         
 4.622s dev-loop18.device                                                                        
 4.243s dev-loop8.device                                                                         
 4.159s gpu-manager.service                                                                      
 4.125s grub-initrd-fallback.service                                                             
 3.970s grub-common.service                                                                      
 3.575s dev-loop1.device                                                                         
 3.387s secureboot-db.service                                                                    
 3.364s dev-loop3.device                                                                         
 2.225s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                                                           
 2.209s preload.service                                                                          
 2.186s rsyslog.service                                                                          
 1.903s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0477ac9e\x2d193b\x2d4e88\x2dacf2\x2d1f7d62755a79.service
 1.593s apport.service                                                                           
 1.430s lm-sensors.service                                                                       
 1.422s colord.service                                                                           
 1.216s systemd-udevd.service                                                                    
 1.194s upower.service                                                                           
 1.180s systemd-backlight@leds:dell::kbd_backlight.service                                       
 1.136s snapd.apparmor.service                                                                   
 1.047s apparmor.service                                                                         
  937ms systemd-random-seed.service                                                              
  926ms snap-anbox-186.mount                                                                     
  919ms xfstt.service                                                                            
  820ms e2scrub_reap.service                                                                     
  743ms kerneloops.service                                                                       
  714ms snap-core-10577.mount                                                                    
  703ms plymouth-start.service                                                                   
  640ms pppd-dns.service                                                                         
  628ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                                                       
  606ms snap-snapd-10707.mount                                                                   
  600ms snap-core-10583.mount                                                                    
  568ms systemd-sysctl.service                                                                   
  562ms snap-zoom\x2dclient-125.mount                                                            
  544ms snap-zoom\x2dclient-124.mount                                                            
  542ms snap-core18-1932.mount                                                                   
  538ms snap-core18-1944.mount                                                                   
  534ms tlp.service                                                                              
  533ms snap-snapd-10492.mount                                                                   
  528ms systemd-journald.service                                                                 
  522ms systemd-modules-load.service                                                             
  499ms systemd-resolved.service                                                                 
  461ms keyboard-setup.service                                                                   
  460ms snap-snap\x2dstore-498.mount                                                             
  452ms modprobe@drm.service                                                                     
  416ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                                                           
  373ms snap-jabref-903.mount                                                                    
  366ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-60.mount                                                   
  365ms plymouth-read-write.service                                                              
  353ms console-setup.service                                                                    
  310ms systemd-sysusers.service                                                                 
  295ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-145.mount                                                  
  293ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-66.mount                                                   
  292ms snap-gtk2\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-13.mount                                                   
  291ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1506.mount                                                  
  272ms snap-shutter-27.mount                                                                    
  255ms snap-snap\x2dstore-518.mount                                                             
  249ms systemd-timesyncd.service                                                                
  244ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service                                      
  231ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1514.mount                                                  
  220ms user@1000.service                                                                        
  212ms phpsessionclean.service                                                                  
  205ms snap-jabref-814.mount                                                                    
  205ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                                                             
  187ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-74810b28\x2d0379\x2d406f\x2d99d1\x2dd49dc53c3148.swap                
  167ms openvpn.service                                                                          
  165ms sysstat.service                                                                          
  158ms home.mount                                                                               
  153ms systemd-remount-fs.service                                                               
  126ms ufw.service                                                                              
  114ms dev-hugepages.mount                                                                      
  114ms dev-mqueue.mount                                                                         
  113ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                                                                   
  113ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                                                                 
  111ms kmod-static-nodes.service                                                                
  104ms systemd-user-sessions.service                                                            
   58ms systemd-update-utmp.service                                                              
   44ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service                                                            
   40ms setvtrgb.service                                                                         
   31ms alsa-restore.service                                                                     
   24ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service                                                     
    8ms rtkit-daemon.service                                                                     
    2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                                                            
    1ms sys-kernel-config.mount                                                                  
  906us snapd.socket
```

Comment: @binaryOps20 in HDD

Comment: Should I post the output for `systemd-analyze blame`?

Comment: You can also do that, so that it would be easier for people to help you (I don't know how to fix this).

Comment: Okay @ArchismanPanigrahi

Comment: Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware? Some things to try: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster After I changed those settings my 2016 Skylake based system boots in 8.8 sec & graphical target reached in 5.4 sec. Current last reboot. Using Kubuntu 20.04.