# Ubuntu 20.10 slow boot!

Tags: boot

I made a upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 20.10 in my laptop and I see that it is extremely slow (about 3 minutes).

My laptop is Compaq Presario CQ41 with Intel HD graphics. It has HDD disk, I have a 16GB swap partition and my RAM is 4GB. Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output of `systemd-analyze blame`? This might show what process is taking so long on your Turion II machine 

Comment: Having more swap than RAM, will not normally improve system. If editing large photos or videos, better to add RAM. Some things to check or change: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Comment: I recommend of having 2GB of swap as it is half the size of ram. I have asus laptop with 4GB ram and 20.04 so it requires 2.30 minutes to boot up.@ Robert