# Ubuntu boot taking up a lot of time

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, bootloader

I use dual boot on my pc- Windows 10 + Ubuntu 20.04.
 Windows is on SSD and boots up very fast but Ubuntu on HDD boots up slow 
 This is how system-analyse blame looks. Please help me improve it.

My Laptop Specifications:-
1.
2. 3. RAM -

| My Laptop Specifications: |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **CPU** | **GPU** | **RAM** |
| INTEL i7 9th GEN | NVIDIA GTX 1650Ti | 8GB |

```
 systemd-analyze blame
    2min 647ms fwupd-refresh.service                                
       27.946s plymouth-quit-wait.service                           
       17.614s snapd.service                                        
       12.671s dev-sda5.device                                      
       11.052s apt-daily.service                                    
        9.050s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                   
        8.646s udisks2.service                                      
        8.292s accounts-daemon.service                              
        8.253s networkd-dispatcher.service                          
        7.559s man-db.service                                       
        6.912s dev-loop15.device                                    
        6.297s logrotate.service                                    
        6.054s dev-loop16.device                                    
        6.015s apache2.service                                      
        5.989s dev-loop13.device                                    
        5.879s dev-loop6.device                                     
        5.855s dev-loop12.device                                    
        5.677s polkit.service                                       
        5.674s dev-loop19.device                                    
        5.613s dev-loop18.device                                    
        5.609s dev-loop8.device                                     
        5.389s dev-loop0.device                                     
        5.334s dev-loop7.device
```

Also, the boot time is as follows:-

```
Startup finished in 12.228s (firmware) + 3.910s (loader) + 3.582s (kernel) + 49.578s (userspace) = 1min 9.299s 

graphical.target reached after 49.447s in userspace
```

Comment: `systemctl status fwupd-refresh.service`  And `sudo fwupdmgr --verbose get-updates`  Please add this to your question.

Comment: Some settings to review: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster and links to others