# Why ubuntu 20.04 is taking too much time to startup notebook?

Tags: boot, 20.04

I have installed Ubuntu with below configuration:

OS Name: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 
OS Type: 64-bit 
GONAME Version: 3.36.8 
Windowing System: X11 
Memory: 5.6 GiB (6GB RAM)
Processor: Intel® Core™ i3-3110M CPU @ 2.40GHz × 4 
Graphics: Intel® HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2) 
Disk Capacity: 500.1 GB

Disk Volumes:

|  | Swap Partition 1 | File System Partition 2 | File System Partition 3 | Free Space |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Size | 8 GB | 300 GB — 283 GB free (5.5% full) | 192 GB | 1.1 MB |
| Device | /dev/sda1 | /dev/sda2 | /dev/sda3 | /dev/sda |
| Type | Linux swap | Linux (Bootable) | Linux | - |
| Contents | Swap (version 1) — Active | Ext4 (version 1.0) — Mounted at Filesystem Root | Ext4 (version 1.0) — Not Mounted | Unallocated Space |

> sudo lshw -short -c volume -c disk -c storage

| H/W path | Device | Class | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /0/100/1f.2 |  | storage | 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] |
| /0/a | scsi0 | storage |  |
| /0/a/0.0.0 | /dev/sda | disk | 500GB WDC WD5000BPVT-2 |
| /0/a/0.0.0/1 | /dev/sda1 | volume | 7812MiB Linux swap volume |
| /0/a/0.0.0/2 | /dev/sda2 | volume | 279GiB EXT4 volume |
| /0/a/0.0.0/3 | /dev/sda3 | volume | 178GiB EXT4 volume |
| /0/b | scsi5 | storage |  |
| /0/b/0.0.0 | /dev/cdrom | disk | DVD-RAM UJ8C0 |

It takes about 1 to 2 minutes to startup notebook,

> systemd-analyze

```
Startup finished in 3.765s (kernel) + 58.381s (userspace) = 1min 2.147s 
graphical.target reached after 58.260s in userspace
```

> systemd-analyze blame

```
29.835s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                               
19.295s dev-sda2.device                                                          
14.408s snapd.service                                                            
11.184s fwupd.service                                                            
10.737s networkd-dispatcher.service                                              
10.721s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                                       
 9.088s udisks2.service                                                          
 8.335s dev-loop11.device                                                        
 7.236s accounts-daemon.service                                                  
 7.065s dev-loop0.device                                                         
 7.065s dev-loop2.device                                                         
 7.064s dev-loop5.device                                                         
 7.063s dev-loop4.device                                                         
 7.063s dev-loop10.device                                                        
 7.062s dev-loop9.device                                                         
 7.062s dev-loop1.device                                                         
 7.062s dev-loop3.device                                                         
 7.062s dev-loop8.device                                                         
 7.061s dev-loop6.device                                                         
 7.059s dev-loop7.device                                                         
 6.915s dev-loop12.device                                                        
 5.793s NetworkManager.service                                                   
 5.387s polkit.service                                                           
 4.475s systemd-udevd.service                                                    
 4.308s avahi-daemon.service                                                     
 4.302s bluetooth.service                                                        
 3.743s ModemManager.service                                                     
 3.499s switcheroo-control.service                                               
 3.492s thermald.service                                                         
 3.489s systemd-logind.service                                                   
 3.488s wpa_supplicant.service                                                   
 3.308s systemd-journal-flush.service                                            
 2.637s gpu-manager.service                                                      
 2.528s user@1000.service                                                        
 2.462s apparmor.service                                                         
 2.276s colord.service                                                           
 1.745s e2scrub_reap.service                                                     
 1.727s gdm.service                                                              
 1.692s apport.service                                                           
 1.672s grub-common.service                                                      
 1.552s rsyslog.service                                                          
 1.550s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                                           
 1.216s snapd.apparmor.service                                                   
 1.202s systemd-sysctl.service                                                   
 1.084s systemd-resolved.service                                                 
  962ms pppd-dns.service                                                         
  921ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service                      
  891ms systemd-modules-load.service                                             
  762ms snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-95.mount                                     
  717ms snap-chromium-1497.mount                                                 
  716ms snap-code-55.mount                                                       
  673ms snap-core-10823.mount                                                    
  653ms grub-initrd-fallback.service                                             
  631ms snap-core18-1988.mount                                                   
  624ms upower.service                                                           
  577ms snapd.seeded.service                                                     
  576ms systemd-journald.service                                                 
  574ms systemd-sysusers.service                                                 
  560ms modprobe@drm.service                                                     
  519ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-145.mount                                  
  471ms systemd-timesyncd.service                                                
  467ms plymouth-read-write.service                                              
  464ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-66.mount                                   
  463ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                                             
  463ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1514.mount                                  
  393ms systemd-random-seed.service                                              
  382ms keyboard-setup.service                                                   
  370ms ufw.service                                                              
  353ms snap-skype-164.mount                                                     
  331ms kerneloops.service                                                       
  321ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                                       
  270ms apport-autoreport.service                                                
  188ms snap-snap\x2dstore-518.mount                                             
  164ms openvpn.service                                                          
  157ms snap-vlc-2103.mount                                                      
  155ms snap-snapd-11107.mount                                                   
  150ms systemd-remount-fs.service                                               
  132ms snap-snapd-11036.mount                                                   
  118ms console-setup.service                                                    
  117ms setvtrgb.service                                                         
  106ms plymouth-start.service                                                   
   89ms dev-hugepages.mount                                                      
   88ms dev-mqueue.mount                                                         
   88ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-14f1320b\x2d695f\x2d41e4\x2daf30\x2d63d64a1d1221.swap
   87ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                                                   
   85ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                                                 
   82ms systemd-user-sessions.service                                            
   78ms kmod-static-nodes.service                                                
   74ms systemd-update-utmp.service                                              
   65ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                                           
   54ms snap-chromium-1506.mount                                                 
   54ms rtkit-daemon.service                                                     
   41ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service                                            
   18ms alsa-restore.service                                                     
   12ms dev-loop13.device                                                        
   10ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service                                     
    5ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                                            
    5ms mongodb.service                                                          
    5ms systemd-rfkill.service                                                   
    4ms sys-kernel-config.mount                                                  
  963us snapd.socket
```

> systemd-analyze critical-chain

```
graphical.target @58.260s
└─multi-user.target @58.260s
  └─kerneloops.service @39.099s +331ms
    └─network-online.target @39.051s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @28.329s +10.721s
        └─NetworkManager.service @22.533s +5.793s
          └─dbus.service @22.530s
            └─basic.target @22.411s
              └─sockets.target @22.411s
                └─snapd.socket @22.409s +963us
                  └─sysinit.target @22.276s
                    └─swap.target @22.275s
                      └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-14f1320b\x2d695f\x2d41e4\x2daf30\x2d63d64a1d1221.swap @22.185s +88ms
                        └─dev-sda1.device @22.184s
```

Comment: You did not say how much ram you have or the CPU. How fast do you think it should be?

Comment: @David I have added that details, on average it should be less than 1 minute.

Comment: I have many computers now laptop and desktop and server and have had many in the past never had a machine start in under 1 min. Good luck.

Comment: Probably your disk is an old and very low rpm HDD. Can you add your disk's specs too?

Comment: Get an ssd as a main disk and it will be under 13 seconds.

Comment: Can you add information about your disk make and model or at least the output of something like: `sudo lshw -short -c volume -c disk -c storage`?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli i have added details.

Comment: Your disk seems to be an old (8 year old?) hard disk with 5400 RPM speed. As @Rinzwind said, you will probably get a good speed increase if you replace it with an appropriate SSD.

Comment: @Rinzwind thanks for your reply i don't have any knowledge about how to change disk but i will definitely learn and will try as per your suggestion, will get back to you.

Comment: Replacing notebook disk is a relatively easy process depending on the model of your notebook. You will find many videos on Youtube (search your specific model). Be sure to come back and answer your question. The `systemd-analyze` output for my two year I7, SSD, 24GB notebook is something like `Startup finished in 3.872s (firmware) + 7.457s (loader) + 2.898s (kernel) + 15.221s (userspace) = 29.450s 
  graphical.target reached after 9.385s in userspace`. OS is Ubuntu 20.10.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli thank you for your information, definitely i will do that.

Comment: Some settings you can review and may help some, but SSD may also need some of them to give best results. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster Check that UUID of swap is correct as shown in link.