# ubuntu boot very slow after clonning from HDD to SSD using gparted partition clonning

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, ssd, gparted, clone

I bought a new samsung evo 870 ssd and wanted to clone my existing ubuntu partition from HDD.

After referring multiple articles I clonned it using gparted partition clonning and then the ubuntu boot is extremely slow.

Once the system is booted, it runs supper fast. I event checked the partition type and it was GPT and not MBR.

Can anyone help? I dont want to take the hassle of fresh installation.

Comment: Did you update system UEFI and update SSD firmware? Are you booting with UEFI or BIOS? Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred Thank you for getting back.
Yes I'm booting using BIOS and as requested here's a pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report 
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jmkjVDrjTw/

Comment: You are booting in UEFI boot mode for both Windows & Ubuntu. Boot up thru grub looks normal. Does grub menu come up when you boot ubuntu entry in UEFI boot? Line 204 in report shows fstab entry for both swap partition and swap file. No swap partition shown. It may then be slow as it has to timeout on trying to find missing partition. Comment out with # or remove from fstab the swap partition mount, leave swap file mount in fstab. `sudo nano /etc/fstab`, check if ok with `sudo mount -a` Some other settings: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Comment: Does grub menu come up when you boot ubuntu entry in UEFI boot?
=> Yes.

Did all changes as suggested for the `sudo nano /etc/fstab` still the issue persists. Its only during the boot that it is extremely slow, once booted it runs super smooth

Comment: Review link on other settings. Check `systemd-analyze` and `systemd-analyze blame` And boot log files for any process that is slow or long time. this may have many entries, some not really an issue:  `sudo egrep -i 'warn|error' /var/log/*g` or just review for any slow entry or multiple tries to load something.