# Terribly slow boot

Tags: boot

This is first time I am using Linux system. It takes long time to boot and shut down. Also the installation felt really slow. Had to use boot-repair to be able to boot windows again, it added another windows in the grub menu.

systemd-analyze blame

```
41.724s udisks2.service                        
37.413s dev-sdb5.device                        
20.853s plymouth-quit-wait.service             
 9.612s upower.service                         
 5.472s NetworkManager-wait-online.service     
 1.160s snapd.service                          
  880ms fwupd.service                          
  712ms mnt-DISK.mount                         
  379ms dev-loop1.device                       
  361ms dev-loop2.device                       
  361ms dev-loop3.device                       
  353ms systemd-logind.service                 
  291ms dev-loop5.device                       
  291ms dev-loop4.device                       
  287ms networkd-dispatcher.service
```

systemd-analyze critical-chain udisks2.service

```
udisks2.service +41.724s
└─basic.target @1min 30.733s
  └─sockets.target @1min 30.733s
    └─snapd.socket @1min 30.732s +1ms
      └─sysinit.target @1min 30.723s
        └─systemd-timesyncd.service @1min 30.523s +199ms
          └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @1min 30.481s +37ms
            └─systemd-journal-flush.service @444ms +241ms
              └─systemd-journald.service @250ms +192ms
                └─systemd-journald.socket @244ms
                  └─-.mount @241ms
                    └─system.slice @241ms
                      └─-.slice @241ms
```

Comment: Figure out why it's taking 37 seconds to mount sdb5. Historically, 42 seconds is blindingly fast. A decade ago, 1-2 minutes was common.

Comment: Some things to check. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster if sda5 is part of issue, does it need chkdsk, if NTFS or fsck if ext4,or have incorrect mount in fstab?

Comment: @oldfred its SSD partition with my Windows system, I believe its mounted correctly based on the UUID

Comment: its not big deal tho, I intend to use Windows as little as possible

Comment: Then it may have fast start up on, which sets hibernation flag preventing Linux NTFS driver from fully seeing it. Note Windows regularly turns fast startup back on, so if issues you may need to turn it off again. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Its W7 so there is no fast boot and I checked BIOS and its also disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well of course now that I asked for help, I found a solution... Updating grub seems fixed it. Takes just few secs now.

edit: Actually it fixed only the udisks2.service part of the problem.

```
40.382s dev-sdb5.device                        
21.190s plymouth-quit-wait.service             
12.598s snapd.service                          
 5.566s NetworkManager-wait-online.service     
 1.008s gpu-manager.service                    
  812ms fwupd.service                          
  709ms mnt-DISK.mount                         
  695ms udisks2.service
```