# Ubuntu Slow Boot

Tags: boot

I have a Lenevo L340-15IWL Laptop (ideapad) - Type 81LG and I really wanna use Ubuntu but when I install Ubuntu it boot very slow approx 3-4 min compare to windows which takes less than 10 sec to boot is there any way to have the same boot time as windows on ubuntu currently I am using Windows.

Comment: Some settings to review: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop may have a hard drive, which slows your boot time by A LOT. If you (accedentally) installed your Ubuntu on the hard drive instead of the SSD (where windows is on at the moment), you have the boot time issues you are running into at the moment.

Fix: Reinstall Ubuntu and make sure you install ubuntu on the same "hard drive" as Windows is on.

If this doesn't help fully, this is normal (I have it this problem partionally on my laptop too), but this should cut your boot time at least in half (probably faster :) )