# ubuntu 20.04 is taking too long to boot

Tags: boot, 20.04, startup

Can anybody help me improve my boot time?

my specs:

> OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS x86_64
>
> CPU: Intel i7-7700HQ (8) @ 3.800GHz
>
> GPU: Intel HD Graphics 630
>
> GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile
>
> RAM: 15897MiB

---

systemd-analyze blame:

> 45.089s plymouth-quit-wait.service
> 35.392s snapd.service
> 20.055s dev-sdb3.device
> 17.658s systemd-journal-flush.service
> 16.274s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
> 11.665s dev-loop23.device
> 10.702s dev-loop29.device
> 10.690s dev-loop37.device
> 10.444s dev-loop34.device
> 10.184s dev-loop31.device
> 10.159s dev-loop35.device
> 9.648s dev-loop28.device
> 9.611s dev-loop3.device
> 9.608s dev-loop8.device
> 9.608s dev-loop12.device
> 9.607s dev-loop9.device
> 9.602s dev-loop27.device
> 9.545s dev-loop33.device
> 9.483s dev-loop36.device
>
> etc.

---

If you need any additional information or would like me to run any command to help you help me please do not hesitate to ask.

Thx!

Comment: Read your output, and then ask yourself: Why is /dev/sdb3 taking 20 seconds to mount?

Comment: @user535733 do you have any idea?

*size*: 500 GB — 421 GB free (15,8% full)
*partition type*: Linux Filesystem
*contents*: Ext4 (version 1.0) — Mounted at Filesystem Root

Comment: You need to investigate. Start with the logs of your last boot. One common problem is a mistake in /etc/fstab. Lots of possibilities. This is a perfect opportunity to learn how boot works. Most folks install Linux because they want to learn and tinker.

Comment: Look specifically for renamed interfaces and mount failures. Use `grep` to make searching the logs easier. If you discover something, add it to your question above (DON'T put it in a comment).

Comment: You have too many snaps. Each snap increases boot time. Have you run `fsck` on your boot drive? Edit your question and show me the `Disks` app **SMART Data & Tests** data window. This is a scrollable window, so it may take two screenshots.

Comment: Some more things to check. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Comment: @heynnema yeah i also noticed that the snaps were taking a lot of boot time, should i reinstall them without using snap? (i have never run that fsck command) Also, the question is updated as you asked

Comment: thanks! @oldfred

Comment: @atfortes Yes, I'd consider changing out the snap apps for regular binary (.deb) apps. Your SMART data looks fine. I put together a quick answer with instructions for how to run `fsck` for you.

Comment: @atfortes  Status please...

Comment: @heynnema I have updated the question. I haven't yet followed your instructions for the fsck command because I didn't have much time, but the dev-sdb3.device task is taking less time to complete regardless.

Comment: @atfortes Do `rm -i /var/crash/*.crash`, reboot, and redo `systemd-analyze blame`, and you'll probably be alright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**fsck**

Let's start by checking your file system...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**SMART**

Your SMART Data looks fine. No disk problems.

**snaps**

You have a lot of snap applications that are increasing your boot time (35.392s snapd.service, and all dev-loopxx devices). See `snap list`. Consider uninstalling snap apps, and reinstalling the binary (.deb) versions of the same app, if available.

You'll probably have to keep these snaps...

```
Name                  Version                     Rev    Tracking         Publisher   Notes
core                  16-2.49.2                   10958  latest/stable    canonical✓  core
core18                20210309                    1997   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
gnome-3-28-1804       3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67  145    latest/stable    canonical✓  -
gnome-3-34-1804       0+git.3556cb3               66     latest/stable    canonical✓  -
gnome-system-monitor  3.38.0-17-g38c1ce1d62       157    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes     0.1-52-gb92ac40             1515   latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
gtk2-common-themes    0.1                         13     latest/stable    canonical✓  -
snap-store            3.38.0-59-g494f078          518    latest/stable    canonical✓  -
snapd                 2.49.2                      11588  latest/stable    canonical✓  snapd
```