# Ubuntu 20.04 Booting is 3 times longer than Windows 10

Tags: boot, 20.04, ssd

Windows 10 booting requires 12/15 seconds while Ubuntu 20.04 one requires 40/45 seconds.
Both OSs are installed in SSD Samsung 840 EVO.

I've provided you in advance outputs of some commands (but please suggest me other useful ones).

Thanks in advance.

Here is the log from **systemd-analyze chain**:

```
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @10.465s
└─multi-user.target @10.465s
  └─kerneloops.service @8.657s +10ms
    └─network-online.target @8.651s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @3.343s +5.308s
        └─NetworkManager.service @3.171s +170ms
          └─dbus.service @3.169s
            └─basic.target @3.159s
              └─sockets.target @3.159s
                └─snapd.socket @3.158s +673us
                  └─sysinit.target @3.153s
                    └─snapd.apparmor.service @2.779s +106ms
                      └─apparmor.service @2.660s +118ms
                        └─local-fs.target @2.659s
                          └─run-user-125-gvfs.mount @3.864s
                            └─run-user-125.mount @3.651s
                              └─local-fs-pre.target @343ms
                                └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service @311ms +31ms
                                  └─systemd-sysusers.service @284ms +26ms
                                    └─systemd-remount-fs.service @269ms +12ms
                                      └─systemd-journald.socket @260ms
                                        └─-.mount @257ms
                                          └─system.slice @257ms
                                            └─-.slice @257ms
```

Here is the log from **systemd-analyze blame**:

```
7.103s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                                               
5.308s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                                                       
2.302s snap-core20-975.mount                                                                    
2.262s snap-snapd-11841.mount                                                                   
2.256s snap-youtube\x2ddl-3805.mount                                                            
2.187s snap-skype-173.mount                                                                     
2.124s snap-snap\x2dstore-518.mount                                                             
2.080s dev-sda2.device                                                                          
2.060s snap-pdftk-9.mount                                                                       
1.952s snap-snap\x2dstore-498.mount                                                             
1.947s snap-spotify-46.mount                                                                    
1.862s snap-telegram\x2ddesktop-2637.mount                                                      
1.825s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1514.mount                                                  
1.805s snap-spotify-45.mount                                                                    
1.780s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-60.mount                                                   
1.631s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-66.mount                                                   
1.620s snap-pinta\x2djames\x2dcarroll-8.mount                                                   
1.619s snap-snapd-11588.mount                                                                   
1.617s snap-skype-172.mount                                                                     
1.573s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-145.mount                                                  
1.565s snap-intellij\x2didea\x2dultimate-295.mount                                              
1.546s snap-telegram\x2ddesktop-2619.mount                                                      
1.446s dev-loop2.device                                                                         
1.370s dev-loop3.device                                                                         
1.346s snap-postman-132.mount                                                                   
1.336s snap-core18-1997.mount                                                                   
1.336s dev-loop4.device                                                                         
1.310s snap-postman-133.mount                                                                   
1.220s snap-kde\x2dframeworks\x2d5\x2dqt\x2d5\x2d14\x2dcore18-4.mount                           
1.217s snap-pinta\x2djames\x2dcarroll-6.mount                                                   
1.158s snapd.service                                                                            
1.144s snap-acestreamplayer-11.mount                                                            
1.131s snap-datagrip-107.mount                                                                  
1.122s systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service                                      
1.118s dev-loop5.device                                                                         
1.097s dev-loop0.device                                                                         
1.051s dev-loop8.device                                                                         
1.003s dev-loop1.device                                                                         
 999ms dev-loop6.device                                                                         
 978ms dev-loop7.device                                                                         
 908ms dev-loop9.device                                                                         
 855ms dev-loop11.device                                                                        
 852ms dev-loop10.device                                                                        
 814ms fwupd.service                                                                            
 615ms dev-loop12.device                                                                        
 555ms snap-intellij\x2didea\x2dultimate-289.mount                                              
 552ms snap-kde\x2dframeworks\x2d5\x2dqt\x2d5\x2d15\x2dcore20-14.mount                          
 518ms networkd-dispatcher.service                                                              
 491ms plymouth-read-write.service                                                              
 488ms dev-loop14.device                                                                        
 483ms snap-code-64.mount                                                                       
 476ms snap-core20-1026.mount                                                                   
 440ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1515.mount                                                  
 437ms udisks2.service                                                                          
 435ms snapd.seeded.service                                                                     
 431ms snap-code-65.mount                                                                       
 415ms snap-gtk2\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-13.mount                                                   
 395ms upower.service                                                                           
 360ms dev-loop16.device                                                                        
 349ms snap-datagrip-106.mount                                                                  
 342ms systemd-logind.service                                                                   
 322ms snap-core-11081.mount                                                                    
 291ms systemd-rfkill.service                                                                   
 283ms dev-loop17.device                                                                        
 276ms dev-loop20.device                                                                        
 229ms accounts-daemon.service                                                                  
 223ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-8732e59a\x2d2720\x2d48f9\x2dafaf\x2d206471a8ed59.service
 223ms systemd-journal-flush.service                                                            
 218ms systemd-udevd.service                                                                    
 196ms dev-loop25.device                                                                        
 194ms dev-loop13.device                                                                        
 192ms systemd-resolved.service                                                                 
 192ms dev-loop15.device                                                                        
 192ms dev-loop19.device                                                                        
 171ms avahi-daemon.service                                                                     
 170ms NetworkManager.service                                                                   
 170ms bluetooth.service                                                                        
 165ms polkit.service                                                                           
 165ms dev-loop31.device                                                                        
 161ms snap-core18-2066.mount                                                                   
 157ms dev-loop30.device                                                                        
 155ms systemd-timesyncd.service                                                                
 146ms switcheroo-control.service                                                               
 141ms thermald.service                                                                         
 139ms wpa_supplicant.service                                                                   
 137ms dev-loop27.device                                                                        
 134ms dev-loop26.device                                                                        
 133ms dev-loop18.device                                                                        
 127ms systemd-journald.service                                                                 
 124ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                                                             
 118ms apparmor.service                                                                         
 114ms user@125.service                                                                         
 113ms gpu-manager.service                                                                      
 112ms user@1000.service                                                                        
 109ms snap-core-10958.mount                                                                    
 106ms snapd.apparmor.service                                                                   
 103ms dev-loop33.device                                                                        
 102ms dev-loop24.device                                                                        
  98ms apt-daily-upgrade.service                                                                
  96ms dev-loop28.device                                                                        
  92ms apache2.service                                                                          
  88ms geoclue.service                                                                          
  81ms grub-common.service                                                                      
  74ms ModemManager.service                                                                     
  73ms keyboard-setup.service                                                                   
  70ms apport.service                                                                           
  69ms dev-loop32.device                                                                        
  59ms dev-loop23.device                                                                        
  56ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-DD37\x2dA40E.service                                    
  55ms dev-loop22.device                                                                        
  55ms dev-loop21.device                                                                        
  53ms systemd-random-seed.service                                                              
  51ms e2scrub_reap.service                                                                     
  47ms systemd-sysctl.service                                                                   
  41ms rsyslog.service                                                                          
  40ms colord.service                                                                           
  39ms grub-initrd-fallback.service                                                             
  39ms gdm.service                                                                              
  34ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                                                           
  31ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                                                       
  30ms dev-loop35.device                                                                        
  26ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                                                           
  26ms systemd-sysusers.service                                                                 
  23ms systemd-modules-load.service                                                             
  21ms plymouth-start.service                                                                   
  19ms home.mount                                                                               
  19ms user-runtime-dir@125.service                                                             
  17ms nvidia-persistenced.service                                                              
  15ms modprobe@drm.service                                                                     
  14ms pppd-dns.service                                                                         
  14ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service                                                            
  13ms dev-hugepages.mount                                                                      
  12ms systemd-remount-fs.service                                                               
  12ms dev-mqueue.mount                                                                         
  11ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                                                                   
  11ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                                                                 
  10ms kerneloops.service                                                                       
  10ms boot-efi.mount                                                                           
   9ms alsa-restore.service                                                                     
   8ms systemd-update-utmp.service                                                              
   8ms kmod-static-nodes.service                                                                
   8ms systemd-user-sessions.service                                                            
   7ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service                                                     
   5ms openvpn.service                                                                          
   5ms dev-loop36.device                                                                        
   4ms console-setup.service                                                                    
   3ms rtkit-daemon.service                                                                     
   3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                                                            
   3ms ufw.service                                                                              
   2ms setvtrgb.service                                                                         
   2ms sys-kernel-config.mount                                                                  
   1ms dev-loop29.device                                                                        
 673us snapd.socket
```

Here is the log from **systemd-analyse**

```
Startup finished in 3.289s (firmware) + 7.828s (loader) + 35.232s (kernel) + 12.593s (userspace) = 58.943s 
graphical.target reached after 12.583s in userspace
```

Kernel Log (dmesg):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rxr-TZuYXvwSyRz-PQkBW4iiNf5dKUL3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: There are too many `snap` services, according to your output of `systemd-analyze blame`. You can consider replacing them with their .deb counterparts.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Thanks for your answer. Do snap packages come from using "Ubuntu Software" for installations? Should I always prefer using apt-get install ?

Comment: *Should I always prefer using apt-get install* -- That is your personal choice.  Nowadays "Ubuntu Software" often defaults to snap over apt. While snap is a great way to get the newest version of certain apps, they are sometimes not as fast as native apps. However, this is not a complete answer to the question (that is why I commented instead of answering). Someone else may be able to provide a better answer regarding other services which can be safely disabled.

Comment: Is your Windows boot time from cold? If you start up from one of the suspended states it’s not really a valid comparison.

Comment: @PonJar I've disabled fast boot.

Comment: This will not be due to snap. Added delays by added snap packages are some microseconds at most. Indeed, fair comparison would be if also Windows would be cold booted (so no fast start enabled, and after fully shutting it down). Still, I find 40 s quite long for a system booting from SSD.

Comment: What is the output of `systemd-analyse` without arguments? What you reported is time in userspace, and that actually looks quite normal.

Comment: @vanadium I've just posted ouput of systemd-analyse

Comment: It is the kernel that is stuck. Once it is past there, all is normal. You should inspect kernel logs.

Comment: @vanadium Should I try with dmesg?

Comment: There are system and boot logs, but, like you, I would need to search how to retrieve them.

Comment: @vanadium I've just posted kernel logs by submitting dmesg.

Comment: In kernel log, you can see that strange thing happens between 1053rd row and 1054th row.

Comment: Do I have to format in order to solve the problem (I have already an home partition so I won't loose personal data). Or can I try other things?

Comment: Some things to review. I think I boot a bit fast since Kubuntu, not Ubuntu. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Answer (score 0):

As some of the commenters, I suggest you replace all snaps with their .deb variants. This should boost your boot time significantly. You don't really need to use sudo apt install for that.

Perhaps as yourself, I prefer the graphical installation through the Ubuntu Software. Whenever you want to install something from there, check the upper right corner. There should be a drop-down menu with words such as "ubuntu-focal-SOMETHING" or "latest/stable". If its the former, you're good to go: the .deb package will be installed. If it's the latter, then this is a Snap package, and I suggest you choose whatever "ubuntu-focal-SOMETHING" option there is.

If there is only the Snap option in Ubuntu Software, you can always go to your preferred software's website page and download a .deb package directly from there. Installing this package will also connect you to the official PPA of that app which will enable automatic updates. This is how you can get the .deb packages for Skype and Spotify apps. Telegram is available as a .deb in Ubuntu Software. You can check Pinta yourself. As for the YouTube app, it's probably just the website in a desktop wrapper, so you may consider simply watching YouTube in Firefox, or get a website wrapper app .deb package. But that's a different question.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not the solution. It is the kernel that takes a long time. Moreover, easy enough to test: remove all snaps, see that the boottime has not decreased and reinstall the snaps again.

Comment: @Igor Thanks for the clarification about snap vs deb

Comment: No problem!

@vanadium I don't mean to say that this is THE solution, for there may be other issues. But the snaps do take long to boot, especially autostarting ones such as Skype and Telegram, so this will help to an extent.