# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS very Slow to Boot

Tags: 20.04

This version of Ubuntu takes very  long time to boot

Motherboard:  ASRock H81M-DGS
Kernel:            Linux 5.8.0-59-generic (x86_64
Processor:       Celeron CPU G1840 @2.80GHz x2
Memory:         8GB
Graphics = Intel HD Graphics (HSW GT1)
HDD = 500.1 GB

`systemd-analyze time
luis@luis-desktop:~$  systemd-analyze time
Startup finished in 3.368s (kernel) + 2min 17.716s (userspace) = 2min 21.084s 
graphical.target reached after 2min 17.668s in userspace
luis@luis-desktop:~$`


With stopwatch takes  4m 32s.

What can be done to fix this?
Thank you

Comment: Can you also add the output of `systemd-analyze blame`?  Thank you!

Comment: Some settings to review: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster But converting to an SSD would make major improvement in boot & app load times.

Answer (score 0):

The command does not come to an end I wait for 30 minutes it looks it come to complete stop.

luis@luis-desktop:~$ systemd-analyze blame
1min 4.934s apt-daily-upgrade.service
37.708s plymouth-quit-wait.service
35.603s man-db.service
23.313s snapd.service
19.481s systemd-journal-flush.service
18.481s dev-sda5.device
17.987s accounts-daemon.service
17.927s networkd-dispatcher.service
14.990s udisks2.service
12.843s logrotate.service
12.678s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
11.452s polkit.service
11.333s dev-loop14.device
11.017s NetworkManager.service
11.011s dev-loop16.device
10.959s dev-loop8.device
10.948s switcheroo-control.service
10.945s thermald.service
10.858s systemd-logind.service
10.221s wpa_supplicant.service
10.210s dev-loop17.device
9.882s dev-loop15.device
9.587s dev-loop3.device
lines 1-23...skipping...
1min 4.934s apt-daily-upgrade.service
37.708s plymouth-quit-wait.service
35.603s man-db.service
23.313s snapd.service
19.481s systemd-journal-flush.service
18.481s dev-sda5.device
17.987s accounts-daemon.service
17.927s networkd-dispatcher.service
14.990s udisks2.service
12.843s logrotate.service
12.678s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
11.452s polkit.service
11.333s dev-loop14.device
11.017s NetworkManager.service
11.011s dev-loop16.device
10.959s dev-loop8.device
10.948s switcheroo-control.service
10.945s thermald.service
10.858s systemd-logind.service
10.221s wpa_supplicant.service
10.210s dev-loop17.device
9.882s dev-loop15.device
9.587s dev-loop3.device
9.575s dev-loop5.device
lines 1-24...skipping...
1min 4.934s apt-daily-upgrade.service
37.708s plymouth-quit-wait.service
35.603s man-db.service
23.313s snapd.service
19.481s systemd-journal-flush.service
18.481s dev-sda5.device
17.987s accounts-daemon.service
17.927s networkd-dispatcher.service
14.990s udisks2.service
12.843s logrotate.service
12.678s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
11.452s polkit.service
11.333s dev-loop14.device
11.017s NetworkManager.service
11.011s dev-loop16.device
10.959s dev-loop8.device
10.948s switcheroo-control.service
10.945s thermald.service
10.858s systemd-logind.service
10.221s wpa_supplicant.service
10.210s dev-loop17.device
9.882s dev-loop15.device
9.587s dev-loop3.device
9.575s dev-loop5.device
9.512s grub-common.service
lines 1-25...skipping...
1min 4.934s apt-daily-upgrade.service
37.708s plymouth-quit-wait.service
35.603s man-db.service
23.313s snapd.service
19.481s systemd-journal-flush.service
18.481s dev-sda5.device
17.987s accounts-daemon.service
17.927s networkd-dispatcher.service
14.990s udisks2.service
12.843s logrotate.service
12.678s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
11.452s polkit.service
11.333s dev-loop14.device
11.017s NetworkManager.service
11.011s dev-loop16.device
10.959s dev-loop8.device
10.948s switcheroo-control.service
10.945s thermald.service
10.858s systemd-logind.service
10.221s wpa_supplicant.service
10.210s dev-loop17.device
9.882s dev-loop15.device
9.587s dev-loop3.device
9.575s dev-loop5.device
9.512s grub-common.service
9.405s dev-loop12.device
lines 1-26...skipping...
1min 4.934s apt-daily-upgrade.service
37.708s plymouth-quit-wait.service
35.603s man-db.service
23.313s snapd.service
19.481s systemd-journal-flush.service
18.481s dev-sda5.device
17.987s accounts-daemon.service
17.927s networkd-dispatcher.service
14.990s udisks2.service
12.843s logrotate.service
12.678s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
11.452s polkit.service
11.333s dev-loop14.device
11.017s NetworkManager.service
11.011s dev-loop16.device
10.959s dev-loop8.device
10.948s switcheroo-control.service
10.945s thermald.service
10.858s systemd-logind.service
10.221s wpa_supplicant.service
10.210s dev-loop17.device
9.882s dev-loop15.device
9.587s dev-loop3.device
9.575s dev-loop5.device
9.512s grub-common.service
9.405s dev-loop12.device
9.006s dev-loop10.device
lines 1-27...skipping...
1min 4.934s apt-daily-upgrade.service
37.708s plymouth-quit-wait.service
35.603s man-db.service
23.313s snapd.service
19.481s systemd-journal-flush.service
18.481s dev-sda5.device
17.987s accounts-daemon.service
17.927s networkd-dispatcher.service
14.990s udisks2.service
12.843s logrotate.service
12.678s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
11.452s polkit.service
11.333s dev-loop14.device
11.017s NetworkManager.service
11.011s dev-loop16.device
10.959s dev-loop8.device
10.948s switcheroo-control.service
10.945s thermald.service
10.858s systemd-logind.service
10.221s wpa_supplicant.service
10.210s dev-loop17.device
9.882s dev-loop15.device
9.587s dev-loop3.device
9.575s dev-loop5.device
9.512s grub-common.service
9.405s dev-loop12.device
9.006s dev-loop10.device
8.721s dev-loop13.device
lines 1-28...skipping...
1min 4.934s apt-daily-upgrade.service
37.708s plymouth-quit-wait.service
35.603s man-db.service
23.313s snapd.service
19.481s systemd-journal-flush.service
18.481s dev-sda5.device
17.987s accounts-daemon.service
17.927s networkd-dispatcher.service
14.990s udisks2.service
12.843s logrotate.service
12.678s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
11.452s polkit.service
11.333s dev-loop14.device
11.017s NetworkManager.service
11.011s dev-loop16.device
10.959s dev-loop8.device
10.948s switcheroo-control.service
10.945s thermald.service
10.858s systemd-logind.service
10.221s wpa_supplicant.service
10.210s dev-loop17.device
9.882s dev-loop15.device
9.587s dev-loop3.device
9.575s dev-loop5.device
9.512s grub-common.service
9.405s dev-loop12.device
9.006s dev-loop10.device
8.721s dev-loop13.device
8.711s dev-loop7.device
lines 1-29...skipping...
1min 4.934s apt-daily-upgrade.service
37.708s plymouth-quit-wait.service
35.603s man-db.service
23.313s snapd.service
19.481s systemd-journal-flush.service
18.481s dev-sda5.device
17.987s accounts-daemon.service
17.927s networkd-dispatcher.service
14.990s udisks2.service
12.843s logrotate.service
12.678s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
11.452s polkit.service
11.333s dev-loop14.device
11.017s NetworkManager.service
11.011s dev-loop16.device
10.959s dev-loop8.device
10.948s switcheroo-control.service
10.945s thermald.service
10.858s systemd-logind.service
10.221s wpa_supplicant.service
10.210s dev-loop17.device
9.882s dev-loop15.device
9.587s dev-loop3.device
9.575s dev-loop5.device
9.512s grub-common.service
9.405s dev-loop12.device
9.006s dev-loop10.device
8.721s dev-loop13.device
8.711s dev-loop7.device
8.423s dev-loop9.device
lines 1-30...skipping...
1min 4.934s apt-daily-upgrade.service
37.708s plymouth-quit-wait.service
35.603s man-db.service
23.313s snapd.service
19.481s systemd-journal-flush.service
18.481s dev-sda5.device
17.987s accounts-daemon.service
17.927s networkd-dispatcher.service
14.990s udisks2.service
12.843s logrotate.service
12.678s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
11.452s polkit.service
11.333s dev-loop14.device
11.017s NetworkManager.service
11.011s dev-loop16.device
10.959s dev-loop8.device
10.948s switcheroo-control.service
10.945s thermald.service
10.858s systemd-logind.service
10.221s wpa_supplicant.service
10.210s dev-loop17.device
9.882s dev-loop15.device
9.587s dev-loop3.device
9.575s dev-loop5.device
9.512s grub-common.service
9.405s dev-loop12.device
9.006s dev-loop10.device
8.721s dev-loop13.device
8.711s dev-loop7.device
8.423s dev-loop9.device
7.888s dev-loop11.device
lines 1-31...skipping...
1min 4.934s apt-daily-upgrade.service
37.708s plymouth-quit-wait.service
35.603s man-db.service
23.313s snapd.service
19.481s systemd-journal-flush.service
18.481s dev-sda5.device
17.987s accounts-daemon.service
17.927s networkd-dispatcher.service
14.990s udisks2.service
12.843s logrotate.service
12.678s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
11.452s polkit.service
11.333s dev-loop14.device
11.017s NetworkManager.service
11.011s dev-loop16.device
10.959s dev-loop8.device
10.948s switcheroo-control.service
10.945s thermald.service
10.858s systemd-logind.service
10.221s wpa_supplicant.service
10.210s dev-loop17.device
9.882s dev-loop15.device
9.587s dev-loop3.device
9.575s dev-loop5.device
9.512s grub-common.service
9.405s dev-loop12.device
9.006s dev-loop10.device
8.721s dev-loop13.device
8.711s dev-loop7.device
8.423s dev-loop9.device
7.888s dev-loop11.device
7.704s dev-loop6.device
lines 1-32...skipping...
1min 4.934s apt-daily-upgrade.service
37.708s plymouth-quit-wait.service
35.603s man-db.service
23.313s snapd.service
19.481s systemd-journal-flush.service
18.481s dev-sda5.device
17.987s accounts-daemon.service
17.927s networkd-dispatcher.service
14.990s udisks2.service
12.843s logrotate.service
12.678s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
11.452s polkit.service
11.333s dev-loop14.device
11.017s NetworkManager.service
11.011s dev-loop16.device
10.959s dev-loop8.device
10.948s switcheroo-control.service
10.945s thermald.service
10.858s systemd-logind.service
10.221s wpa_supplicant.service
10.210s dev-loop17.device
9.882s dev-loop15.device
9.587s dev-loop3.device
9.575s dev-loop5.device
9.512s grub-common.service
9.405s dev-loop12.device
9.006s dev-loop10.device
8.721s dev-loop13.device
8.711s dev-loop7.device
8.423s dev-loop9.device
7.888s dev-loop11.device
7.704s dev-loop6.device
7.587s dev-loop4.device
lines 1-33...skipping...
1min 4.934s apt-daily-upgrade.service
37.708s plymouth-quit-wait.service
35.603s man-db.service
23.313s snapd.service
19.481s systemd-journal-flush.service
18.481s dev-sda5.device
17.987s accounts-daemon.service
17.927s networkd-dispatcher.service
14.990s udisks2.service
12.843s logrotate.service
12.678s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
11.452s polkit.service
11.333s dev-loop14.device
11.017s NetworkManager.service
11.011s dev-loop16.device
10.959s dev-loop8.device
10.948s switcheroo-control.service
10.945s thermald.service
10.858s systemd-logind.service
10.221s wpa_supplicant.service
10.210s dev-loop17.device
9.882s dev-loop15.device
9.587s dev-loop3.device
9.575s dev-loop5.device
9.512s grub-common.service
9.405s dev-loop12.device
9.006s dev-loop10.device
8.721s dev-loop13.device
8.711s dev-loop7.device
8.423s dev-loop9.device
7.888s dev-loop11.device
7.704s dev-loop6.device
7.587s dev-loop4.device
7.571s dev-loop0.device
lines 1-34...skipping...
1min 4.934s apt-daily-upgrade.service
37.708s plymouth-quit-wait.service
35.603s man-db.service
23.313s snapd.service
19.481s systemd-journal-flush.service
18.481s dev-sda5.device
17.987s accounts-daemon.service
17.927s networkd-dispatcher.service
14.990s udisks2.service
12.843s logrotate.service
12.678s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
11.452s polkit.service
11.333s dev-loop14.device
11.017s NetworkManager.service
11.011s dev-loop16.device
10.959s dev-loop8.device
10.948s switcheroo-control.service
10.945s thermald.service
10.858s systemd-logind.service
10.221s wpa_supplicant.service
10.210s dev-loop17.device
9.882s dev-loop15.device
9.587s dev-loop3.device
9.575s dev-loop5.device
9.512s grub-common.service
9.405s dev-loop12.device
9.006s dev-loop10.device
8.721s dev-loop13.device
8.711s dev-loop7.device
8.423s dev-loop9.device
7.888s dev-loop11.device
7.704s dev-loop6.device
7.587s dev-loop4.device
7.571s dev-loop0.device
7.539s dev-loop2.device
lines 1-35...skipping...
1min 4.934s apt-daily-upgrade.service
37.708s plymouth-quit-wait.service
35.603s man-db.service
23.313s snapd.service
19.481s systemd-journal-flush.service
18.481s dev-sda5.device
17.987s accounts-daemon.service
17.927s networkd-dispatcher.service
14.990s udisks2.service
12.843s logrotate.service
12.678s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
11.452s polkit.service
11.333s dev-loop14.device
11.017s NetworkManager.service
11.011s dev-loop16.device
10.959s dev-loop8.device
10.948s switcheroo-control.service
10.945s thermald.service
10.858s systemd-logind.service
10.221s wpa_supplicant.service
10.210s dev-loop17.device
9.882s dev-loop15.device
9.587s dev-loop3.device
9.575s dev-loop5.device
9.512s grub-common.service
9.405s dev-loop12.device
9.006s dev-loop10.device
8.721s dev-loop13.device
8.711s dev-loop7.device
8.423s dev-loop9.device
7.888s dev-loop11.device
7.704s dev-loop6.device
7.587s dev-loop4.device
7.571s dev-loop0.device
7.539s dev-loop2.device
7.445s dev-loop1.device
lines 1-36...skipping...
1min 4.934s apt-daily-upgrade.service
37.708s plymouth-quit-wait.service
35.603s man-db.service
23.313s snapd.service
19.481s systemd-journal-flush.service
18.481s dev-sda5.device
17.987s accounts-daemon.service
17.927s networkd-dispatcher.service
14.990s udisks2.service
12.843s logrotate.service
12.678s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
11.452s polkit.service
11.333s dev-loop14.device
11.017s NetworkManager.service
11.011s dev-loop16.device
10.959s dev-loop8.device
10.948s switcheroo-control.service
10.945s thermald.service
10.858s systemd-logind.service
10.221s wpa_supplicant.service
10.210s dev-loop17.device
9.882s dev-loop15.device
9.587s dev-loop3.device
9.575s dev-loop5.device
9.512s grub-common.service
9.405s dev-loop12.device
9.006s dev-loop10.device
8.721s dev-loop13.device
8.711s dev-loop7.device
8.423s dev-loop9.device
7.888s dev-loop11.device
7.704s dev-loop6.device
7.587s dev-loop4.device
7.571s dev-loop0.device
7.539s dev-loop2.device
7.445s dev-loop1.device
5.434s systemd-udevd.service
lines 1-37...skipping...
1min 4.934s apt-daily-upgrade.service
37.708s plymouth-quit-wait.service
35.603s man-db.service
23.313s snapd.service
19.481s systemd-journal-flush.service
18.481s dev-sda5.device
17.987s accounts-daemon.service
17.927s networkd-dispatcher.service
14.990s udisks2.service
12.843s logrotate.service
12.678s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
11.452s polkit.service
11.333s dev-loop14.device
11.017s NetworkManager.service
11.011s dev-loop16.device
10.959s dev-loop8.device
10.948s switcheroo-control.service
10.945s thermald.service
10.858s systemd-logind.service
10.221s wpa_supplicant.service
10.210s dev-loop17.device
9.882s dev-loop15.device
9.587s dev-loop3.device
9.575s dev-loop5.device
9.512s grub-common.service
9.405s dev-loop12.device
9.006s dev-loop10.device
8.721s dev-loop13.device
8.711s dev-loop7.device
8.423s dev-loop9.device
7.888s dev-loop11.device
7.704s dev-loop6.device
7.587s dev-loop4.device
7.571s dev-loop0.device
7.539s dev-loop2.device
7.445s dev-loop1.device
5.434s systemd-udevd.service
4.976s gpu-manager.service
lines 1-38