# Booting is VERY slow with grub, until either Win-10 or Linux starts

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bios

Recently, my Lenovo Edge E545 (16GB + lots of spare space on my SSD) began to take a few minutes to startup. AFAIK, I didn't change anything, but after the initial BIOS display, the screen goes blank for almost a minute before the GRUB screen shows.
And then, when I press the arrow to make a selection, it takes about a ½ second to move to each selected line.
As well, if I add a default timer to GRUB, the countdown shows the second-counter decrementing each (approx) SIX seconds.
Afterwards it takes about 1-2 minutes for either Windows or Linux to boot.
After that, the chosen OS "seems" to run at speed, but perhaps it's just wishful thinking.
I can provide (parts of) a CPU-Z listing here if asked.

Comment: Addentum-  Note that I configure GRUB2 thru Daniel Richter's "Grub Customizer" and use the default font.

Comment: In my observation, `GRUB Customizer` tends to make a mess of things. What version Ubuntu... or is this something else?

Comment: Some slow boot issues to review: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster  This shows approx boot time: `systemd-analyze` and first few lines may show issues: `systemd-analyze blame`  or `sudo egrep -i 'warn|error' /var/log/*g` If longer then just the errors. I get a few warnings & errors that are not critical.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late to reply, but- PROBLEM SOLVED!
It took TWO MONTHS for Amazon to deliver a 2032 coin-cell + wire and plug from China.
As soon as this was installed in my Lenovo, the slow booting was fixed!

Earlier, I tried jury-rigging my own 2032 battery (99 cents for TWO at the dollar store), but presumably my connectors on it were not adequate.
So a $12 battery with plug (official Lenovo) from China fixed this.
Why not order locally? Well, the Lenovo (North-America) battery was $19 !!
It's just a common 2032, for pete's sake!