# Confused if my OS is on SSD or HDD

Tags: software-installation, hard-drive, ssd

My laptop has both HDD and SSD, I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 and I felt the system is bit slower I checked it with the command "lsblk -d -o name,rota" and I found the sda value  is 1 so I installed it again changing the installation path to (dev/sda) and again the rotation value still shows 1 and the system is slower than before. The only change I observed is in loop values. Can someone please check the attached image and let me know which one is of SSD?

[Before and after changing the installation path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siuuU.jpg)

Comment: Please don't post photos of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: I suggest that you open a terminal window and use the command line tool `lsblk` for example with the following options: `lsblk -o name,size,fstype,label,mountpoint,model`; You may want to make the terminal window wide so that all output for each device will fit into one line.

Comment: You want to install to the NVMe device not sda. The NVMe device is the SSD. You can change some settings & change some defaults to make system boot faster. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Comment: `sda` is the HDD; `nvme` is the SSD. Any modern OS installed in a HDD will be slow.

Comment: Oh got it thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 1):

Open a termial and type `sudo apt-get install gparted`
Then run gparted and it will show you what you want.
`sudo gparted` and then click on View/Device Information from the top menu. Don't mess around, linux doesn't ask you twice so if you delete or format something here you are going to mess it up.

Comment: okay thank you..