# Ubuntu 20.04 taking 7-12 minutes to boot

Tags: boot, 20.04

I only run ubuntu,having core i3 processor,6Gb Ram and HDD hard-disk.
It was ok for me to boot in 3 minutes now the time tripled to 9 minutes.
looks like I went back to dinosaurs age.Any help is appreciable:

1.partial dmesg report below,
[full dmesg Report here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mq4yrjQQ6T/)

```
[  185.357795] [drm] ib test on ring 5 succeeded
[  315.282976] rfkill: input handler disabled
[  325.564405] audit: type=1400 audit(1629455823.941:49): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/snap/snapd/12704/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=1972 comm="snap-confine" capability=4  capname="fsetid"
[  325.564414] audit: type=1400 audit(1629455823.941:50): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/snap/snapd/12704/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=2134 comm="snap-confine" capability=4  capname="fsetid"
[  389.111464] audit: type=1326 audit(1629455887.492:51): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=2 subj=snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software pid=2134 comm="snap-store" exe="/snap/snap-store/547/usr/bin/snap-store" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=314 compat=0 ip=0x7efc87bd9639 code=0x50000
```

2.systemd-analyze blame Report

```
systemd-analyze blame
1min 17.970s virtualbox.service                                        
  1min 312ms apport-autoreport.service                                 
     53.849s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                
     50.136s postgresql@12-main.service                                
     42.343s snapd.service                                             
     34.585s networkd-dispatcher.service                               
     33.416s dev-sda7.device                                           
     31.050s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                        
     26.095s udisks2.service                                           
     25.766s systemd-journal-flush.service                             
     25.318s teamviewerd.service                                       
     24.567s accounts-daemon.service                                   
     22.945s dev-loop11.device                                         
     22.845s dev-loop16.device                                         
     22.744s dev-loop10.device                                         
     22.597s dev-loop12.device                                         
     22.344s dev-loop17.device                                         
     22.185s dev-loop15.device                                         
     21.952s dev-loop9.device                                          
     21.838s dev-loop8.device                                          
     21.081s dev-loop13.device                                         
     20.473s dev-loop14.device                                         
     20.333s dev-loop2.device                                          
     20.264s dev-loop0.device                                          
     20.090s media-jobayer-SAJAL-DESKTOP13.08.20.mount                 
     19.451s dev-loop1.device                                          
     18.845s dev-loop4.device                                          
     17.688s NetworkManager.service                                    
     17.222s dev-loop7.device                                          
     16.577s dev-loop3.device                                          
     16.376s dev-loop6.device                                          
     15.805s polkit.service                                            
     14.379s dev-loop5.device                                          
     13.753s avahi-daemon.service                                      
     13.242s ModemManager.service                                      
     12.887s switcheroo-control.service                                
     12.133s thermald.service                                          
     12.132s systemd-logind.service                                    
     12.129s wpa_supplicant.service
```

3.systemd-analyze critical-chain [here is better view](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tPhnSw75DD/)

```
graphical.target @3min 362ms
└─multi-user.target @3min 362ms
  └─teamviewerd.service @1min 42.389s +25.318s
    └─network-online.target @1min 41.999s
      └─network.target @1min 10.946s
        └─NetworkManager.service @53.257s +17.688s
          └─dbus.service @53.253s
            └─basic.target @53.060s
              └─sockets.target @53.060s
                └─snapd.socket @53.058s +1ms
                  └─sysinit.target @52.329s
                    └─snapd.apparmor.service @49.928s +2.400s
                      └─apparmor.service @46.061s +3.864s
                        └─systemd-journald.socket @9.663s
                          └─system.slice @9.659s
                            └─-.slice @9.659s
```

Comment: Looks like disabling virtualbox at startup will cut off a minute and a half. Id start there. Also every time you see `/dev/loop...` that is Snap.

Comment: Some things to review & links to even more: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster If you want faster boot invest in a SSD. Even a small one just for booting speeds up system a lot.

Comment: Hi Jobayer, can you try and boot back to Kernel 5.8? I have a similar machine. the arrival of 5.11 produced that situation.