# Slow boot on Ubuntu 21.04 (installed twice, same problem)

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu 21.04 yesterday (dual booting with Windows 10) with an SSD (Samsung 970 EVO), Nvidia GPU and AMD CPU. Ubuntu takes >30 seconds to reach the login screen after selecting it on the boot menu and this is significantly longer than Windows 10 which takes <5 seconds. My BIOS splash screen also seems to be taking >10 seconds to load which is notably longer than usual. I've tried these commands to troubleshoot:

- `systemd-analyze blame`:

```
1min 2.842s upower.service
    28.641s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     6.328s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      887ms snapd.service
      579ms snap-snap\x2dstore-547.mount
      576ms snap-snapd-11588.mount
      547ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-72.mount
      467ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1514.mount
      359ms snap-snapd-12883.mount
      349ms snap-core18-1997.mount
      345ms snap-snap\x2dstore-518.mount
      317ms dev-nvme0n1p5.device
      312ms snap-core18-2128.mount
      310ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1515.mount
      293ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-66.mount
      239ms dev-loop1.device
      229ms snapd.seeded.service
      173ms dev-loop2.device
      156ms dev-loop0.device
      155ms dev-loop4.device
      140ms rtkit-daemon.service
      120ms dev-loop5.device
      115ms dev-loop7.device
      103ms dev-loop6.device
      101ms systemd-resolved.service
       82ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       81ms networkd-dispatcher.service
       79ms cups.service
       70ms apparmor.service
       70ms boot-efi.mount
       68ms dev-loop3.device
       67ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       58ms udisks2.service
       56ms accounts-daemon.service
       47ms user@1000.service
       46ms update-notifier-download.service
       45ms gpu-manager.service
       45ms systemd-journald.service
       41ms swapfile.swap
       39ms polkit.service
       39ms avahi-daemon.service
       39ms NetworkManager.service
       38ms bluetooth.service
       32ms power-profiles-daemon.service
       31ms ModemManager.service
       31ms nvidia-persistenced.service
       31ms dev-loop8.device
       29ms switcheroo-control.service
       27ms thermald.service
       27ms keyboard-setup.service
       26ms systemd-logind.service
       25ms wpa_supplicant.service
       25ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       24ms apport.service
       23ms systemd-udevd.service
       23ms systemd-modules-load.service
       22ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
       21ms gdm.service
       19ms secureboot-db.service
       18ms packagekit.service
       16ms snapd.apparmor.service
       15ms plymouth-start.service
       14ms grub-common.service
       14ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-78FD\x2d7191.service
       14ms grub-initrd-fallback.service
       11ms e2scrub_reap.service
       11ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       11ms plymouth-read-write.service
        9ms rsyslog.service
        9ms colord.service
        8ms systemd-random-seed.service
        8ms alsa-restore.service
        7ms pppd-dns.service
        7ms systemd-sysctl.service
        6ms dev-hugepages.mount
        6ms dev-mqueue.mount
        6ms kerneloops.service
        6ms modprobe@drm.service
        6ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
        5ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
        5ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
        5ms systemd-rfkill.service
        5ms systemd-remount-fs.service
        4ms systemd-sysusers.service
        4ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
        4ms kmod-static-nodes.service
        3ms modprobe@configfs.service
        3ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
        3ms modprobe@fuse.service
        3ms dev-loop9.device
        2ms systemd-update-utmp.service
        2ms openvpn.service
        2ms systemd-user-sessions.service
        1ms console-setup.service
        1ms setvtrgb.service
        1ms ufw.service
        1ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
      915us sys-kernel-config.mount
      401us snapd.socket
```

- `systemd-analyze time`

```
Startup finished in 1min 2.982s (firmware) + 7.913s (loader) + 2.216s (kernel) + 1min 4.273s (userspace) = 2min 17.386s 
graphical.target reached after 29.551s in userspace
```

- `systemd-analyze critical-chain upower.service`

```
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

**upower.service +1min 2.842s**
└─dbus.socket @858ms
  └─basic.target @858ms
    └─sockets.target @858ms
      └─snapd.socket @857ms +401us
        └─sysinit.target @855ms
          └─systemd-timesyncd.service @773ms +82ms
            └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @760ms +11ms
              └─local-fs.target @759ms
                └─run-user-1000-gvfs.mount @32.923s
                  └─run-user-1000.mount @32.857s
                    └─swap.target @196ms
                      └─swapfile.swap @155ms +41ms
                        └─systemd-remount-fs.service @149ms +5ms
                          └─systemd-journald.socket @143ms
                            └─-.mount @98ms
                              └─-.slice @98ms
```

- `systemctl status upower`

```
● upower.service - Daemon for power management
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/upower.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since ---
       Docs: man:upowerd(8)
   Main PID: 1174 (upowerd)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 38334)
     Memory: 2.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/upower.service
             └─1174 /usr/libexec/upowerd

Sep 05 13:03:11 user systemd[1]: Starting Daemon for power management...
Sep 05 03:04:14 user upowerd[1174]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
Sep 05 03:04:14 user upowerd[1174]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
Sep 05 03:04:14 user systemd[1]: Started Daemon for power management.
```

- `journalctl "_SYSTEMD_UNIT=upower.service"`

```
Sep 04 22:21:45 user upowerd[3165]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
Sep 04 22:21:45 user upowerd[3165]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
Sep 04 22:21:45 user upowerd[3165]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
-- Boot c3a7df5ead774a29bf789838f8ce7a31 --
Sep 04 22:27:50 user upowerd[3113]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
Sep 04 22:27:50 user upowerd[3113]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
-- Boot e539a154ea5c4d4cb4e859601b246085 --
Sep 04 22:36:27 user upowerd[1148]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
Sep 04 22:36:27 user upowerd[1148]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
-- Boot e0e33d0eafa0448c929fe94849479d09 --
Sep 04 22:43:37 user upowerd[1151]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
Sep 04 22:43:37 user upowerd[1151]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
-- Boot 003933328f0e49d7ba1db41d4b0f9970 --
Sep 04 23:12:09 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
Sep 04 23:12:09 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
-- Boot daf822ba41c74ecbbe4d6b1bc099355e --
Sep 04 23:37:52 user upowerd[1137]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
Sep 04 23:37:52 user upowerd[1137]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
Sep 04 23:37:52 user upowerd[1137]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
-- Boot c290ec183daa48058f559379b4487119 --
Sep 04 23:47:18 user upowerd[1148]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
Sep 04 23:47:18 user upowerd[1148]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
-- Boot e1c431ee19d645b78a93964b02a4a4da --
Sep 04 23:53:30 user upowerd[1142]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
Sep 04 23:53:30 user upowerd[1142]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
-- Boot fe020bfd93f74df482dfaa8ef3dd2616 --
Sep 04 23:58:56 user upowerd[1143]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
Sep 04 23:58:56 user upowerd[1143]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
-- Boot 8cee97cc7de9473cabb3e8a64c3862b3 --
Sep 05 00:02:41 user upowerd[2907]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
Sep 05 00:02:41 user upowerd[2907]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
-- Boot 2677ba1e806f48aaa088716f2f26f5a8 --
Sep 05 00:14:28 user upowerd[1142]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
Sep 05 00:14:28 user upowerd[1142]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
-- Boot 2b7792d83c1a405382c54ca0ba251326 --
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb6
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-0:1.0
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-1
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb6/6-0:1.0
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.0
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.2
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.1
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.0/0003:046D:C539.0004
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:046D:C545.0001
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.2/usbmisc/hiddev0
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.2/0003:046D:C545.0003
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.1/usbmisc/hiddev1
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.1/0003:046D:C539.0005
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:046D:C545.0002
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/usbmisc/hiddev2
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.3/usb3
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.1/usb2
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.1/usb1
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.3/usb4
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.3/usb3/3-0:1.0
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.1/usb2/2-0:1.0
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.1/usb1/1-0:1.0
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.3/usb3/3-2
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.1/usb1/1-6
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.1/usb1/1-5
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.3/usb4/4-0:1.0
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.3/usb4/4-2
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.3/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.1/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.1
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.1/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.3/usb4/4-2/4-2:1.0
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.1/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.1/usb1/1-5/1-5.3
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.1/usb1/1-5/1-5.3/1-5.3:1.0
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.1/usb1/1-5/1-5.3/1-5.3:1.2
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.1/usb1/1-5/1-5.3/1-5.3:1.2/0003:0B05:18F3.0007
Sep 05 00:40:57 user upowerd[1140]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.1/usb1/1-5/1-5.3/1-5.3:1.2/usbmisc/hiddev3
-- Boot 6d33db68a32a4b2bac9d325adf96f0b4 --
Sep 05 00:45:29 user upowerd[1138]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
Sep 05 00:45:29 user upowerd[1138]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
-- Boot 26812a412d9f499eaf8cac593efd6e97 --
Sep 05 01:57:13 user upowerd[1148]: Could not acquire inhibitor lock: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
-- Boot 42d8cd24837a40b5aa8c9e1be4a2add8 --
Sep 05 03:04:14 user upowerd[1174]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
Sep 05 03:04:14 user upowerd[1174]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
-- Boot f7638126c079429f86a60baa1059f202 --
Sep 05 03:17:00 user upowerd[1135]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.3/usb3/3-4
-- Boot 2aac308645fa40bba6bcb46711c94631 --
Sep 05 03:19:23 user upowerd[1176]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.3/usb3/3-2/3-2.1
Sep 05 03:19:23 user upowerd[1176]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.3/usb3/3-2/3-2.1
-- Boot 1134bb77e49040308b3df1ea67e09a5a --
Sep 05 03:20:14 user upowerd[1162]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.3/usb3/3-2/3-2.1
Sep 05 03:20:14 user upowerd[1162]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.3/usb3/3-2/3-2.1
Sep 05 03:20:30 user upowerd[1162]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.000B/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
-- Boot acda6204a8514c1f978ca9471f561858 --
Sep 05 03:23:20 user upowerd[1171]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.3/usb3/3-2/3-2.1
Sep 05 03:23:20 user upowerd[1171]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.3/usb3/3-2/3-2.1
Sep 05 03:23:24 user upowerd[1171]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
Sep 05 03:23:24 user upowerd[1171]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
-- Boot 800f3aea6be04b5183fd14ecde93762d --
Sep 05 03:24:02 user upowerd[1157]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.3/usb3/3-2/3-2.1
Sep 05 03:24:02 user upowerd[1157]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.3/usb3/3-2/3-2.1
Sep 05 03:24:05 user upowerd[1157]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
Sep 05 03:24:05 user upowerd[1157]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
-- Boot 051c32a75bc0416ab2d413c58b9cd129 --
Sep 05 03:29:15 user upowerd[1169]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.3/usb3/3-2/3-2.1
Sep 05 03:29:15 user upowerd[1169]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.3/usb3/3-2/3-2.1
Sep 05 03:29:18 user upowerd[1169]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
Sep 05 03:29:18 user upowerd[1169]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
-- Boot a508efbd79a841b7b29dfbdf822d25df --
Sep 05 03:40:13 user upowerd[1164]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.3/usb3/3-2/3-2.1
Sep 05 03:40:13 user upowerd[1164]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:07:00.3/usb3/3-2/3-2.1
Sep 05 03:40:16 user upowerd[1164]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
Sep 05 03:40:16 user upowerd[1164]: treating change event as add on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:0c:00.3/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.2/0003:046D:C539.0006/0003:046D:407F.0008/power_supply/hidpp_battery_0
```

- `free -m`

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          32075        1711       29190         107        1173       29855
Swap:          2047           0        2047
```

I've tried the changes below but I've had no success so far:

- modifying `/etc/default/grub` with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash noresume"` and updating grub
- modifying `/etc/default/grub` with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"` and updating grub
- checking that the nvidia proprietary drivers are installed (tried `nvidia-driver-470` and `nvidia-driver-460`)

**Edit: Unplugging all my USB devices (and HDMI EDID emulator) and plugging them back in again seems to have fixed all my issues. I will do some more testing to verify this. Thanks @CharlesGreen for the suggestion.**

Comment: Can you append the output of `systemctl status upower` to your question?

Comment: @CharlesGreen: Edited my post to include it.

Comment: Sadly, were about at the limit of my meager abilities.  You might examine `journalctl "_SYSTEMD_UNIT=upower.service"` to see if there are any extraneous error messages, and also unplug any USB devices that you can from your computer and boot again.

Comment: @CharlesGreen: Unplugging all my USB devices (and my HDMI EDID emulator) and plugging them in again seems to have done the trick...I will have to look into what made the difference. It seems all fixed now (both the slow BIOS splash screen and Ubuntu start-up) but I will do some more testing to verify it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Some typical things to review & links to even more solutions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster