# Ubuntu 20.04 low write speed samsung evo 970 plus

Tags: ssd, nvme

I have installed samsung evo 970 plus on Ubuntu. The disk is ok and under windows achive 3,4 / 2,4 GB/s, but under ubuntu 3,2 / 0,6 GB/s.

Seems to be strange and I have no clue what to do.

Thanks in advance Pimco

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and SSD firmware? If also slow boot, some suggestions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Comment: yes everything is the newest and updated. The problem is in write speed - this is what I asking why the transfer is so slow ?

Comment: I can add that the problem depends samsung nvme only. I tested kingston nvme simultaneously and it works fine. Looks like samsung nvme needs some special driver in ubuntu, but I did not find any.

Comment: Did you ever find anything for this? I'm seeing the same read/write in ubuntu