# Is Ubuntu slow when install dual boot with win 10?

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 dual alongside Win 10 on a 1TB NVME SSD. But I feel my Ubuntu is very slow to use as it responds to typing and mouse actions.
Current machine configuration: i7 9700H, 32G Ram.
I turned off swap ram. But the computer system is still slow.
But when I switched to Win, I switched to completely normal and very good.
I thank everyone, hope you can help me fix it because I need to work on linux now. Should I delete Windows 10 to optimize the system?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: I'll give it to you later okay?

Comment: Some settings to review, to see if they apply in your case. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference regarding performance between dual-boot and single-boot configuration. The problem is somewhere else, e.g. graphics adapter.