# 20.04 Boot Problems: Login loop, slow boot, NETPLAN DNS settings not applied after boot, need help

Tags: boot, 20.04, login, netplan

I am running an up-to-date Ubuntu system on a physical PC:

```
Linux 5.13.0-35-generic x86_64
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
```

and I am experiencing the following collection of issues:

- Boot times are suddenly 10x longer than "before"
- The DNS configuration (the DNS addresses to use) is not persisted across
  reboots (after reboot, need to **netplan apply** and it is fine)
- It is impossible to login through the UI (with a directly connected monitor
  and keyboard): the screen accepts a password then asks again -- the "login loop"

These problems started happening after I replaced the main router to which the device is connected. It is configured with a static IP address:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxx:~$ cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      addresses: [192.168.8.221/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.8.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
      dhcp4: no
```

The PC is connected over a wired network to a consumer router that is in turn directly connected to a FIOS ONT. As noted, this problem started after I replace the Verizon-supplied router with my own (and at the same time, the connection speed to the device was increased to 1 GBPS from 100 MBPS).

I literally have no idea where to look for a solution to this -- any advice is welcomed!

Comment: You have posed 3 questions. It is best to pose each question separately. At first glance with the info provided it does not appear they are related. Can I suggest you work on solving one problem at a time?

Comment: Well, I've been looking at various threads for the individual problems, but none of them has been productive. The issues seem to be related to something happening during system startup, like a service or device that takes an unexpectedly long time to start.

Comment: For example, the "login loop" problem is normally attributed to permissions problems caching the entered credentials, but all the permissions seem OK.

Comment: Failure to apply DNS settings during boot is normally attributed to a problem with NVIDIA drivers, but this system doesn't have an NVIDIA display card.

Comment: I guess what I'm really looking for is information about how to analyze all of the things that happen during boot -- that's what all these issues seem to have in common...

Comment: Some things to review. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster Issues may not all be related to new router.  Did new router change default addresses, or change DHCP defaults? Or conflict between a fixed and assigned address.

Comment: Uh where exactly are you seeing problems with applying DNS settings attributed to Nvidia drivers?

Comment: @oldfred Network connectivity in/out is unaffected. The static IP is excluded from DHCP on the router.

Comment: @slangasek I must have dreamt the Nvidia part -- I can't find the reference.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved both problems by reinstalling the display manager. I found the instructions here [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop?answertab=modifieddesc#tab-top) to be helpful.