# How can I transfer my whole ubuntu partition space to newly installed SSD in a dual boot system?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I am having a system of dual boot with ubuntu and windows. But the system is running too slow even ubuntu os is not performing good. So I am thinking of installing a new SSD into my system. Is there any way I can transfer the whole ubuntu partition space to newly installed SSD and run ubuntu in SSD and windows on HDD.
My system is i5 8th gen with 2tb hdd, and I installed the latest version of ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Hello. If your system is a slow as you imply it is a new SSD is not going to fix it. What are the hardware specs? What is the version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Please edit the question and ad this not as a comment, thanks.

Comment: Better to do new install to SSD & restore from your normal backup. Then you know your backup is good when a drive totally fails & you have to use backup. SSD will be faster, but you also can possibly make some changes. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Comment: With those specs you should get a good boost from a SSD. You can transfer your Ubuntu partitions to the SSD but there will be a few hurdles to overcome. @oldfred offers good advice.

Comment: You're performing a Well-Known Error. You're applying a "solution" *before* diagnosing the problem. Why is your system slow? What do the logs show? How about `free`? Do you have swap?

Comment: @waltinator when I see log, there are approx 8 numbered cpu and few of them consumes 100% cpu whenever I  run any application.