# Slow boot after restoring GRUB on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, grub2, boot-repair

I recently deleted the efi partition on my drive by accident. I was able to restore GRUB manually and am now able to use dual boot just as before.

The problem is that now i am facing extremely long boot times on Ubuntu. I didn't have this issue before and i also do not have this problem on my second OS (Windows). The boot time before the accident used to be around 10s.

Running `systemd-analyze` yields the following:

```
(base) pmoritz@moritz-PC:~$ systemd-analyze 
Startup finished in 8.119s (firmware) + 14.240s (loader) + 2.003s (kernel) + 1min 43.588s (userspace) = 2min 7.951s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 43.577s in userspace


(base) pmoritz@moritz-PC:~$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 43.577s
└─multi-user.target @1min 43.577s
  └─docker.service @1min 38.910s +1.115s (red)
    └─network-online.target @1min 38.909s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1min 30.507s +8.401s (red)
        └─NetworkManager.service @1min 30.355s +150ms (red)
          └─dbus.service @1min 30.353s
            └─basic.target @1min 30.344s
              └─sockets.target @1min 30.344s
                └─snapd.socket @1min 30.343s +836us (red)
                  └─sysinit.target @1min 30.339s
                    └─snapd.apparmor.service @1min 30.331s +8ms (red)
                      └─apparmor.service @1min 30.282s +48ms (red)
                        └─systemd-journald.socket @187ms
                          └─-.mount @185ms
                            └─system.slice @185ms
                              └─-.slice @185ms
```

Here is the output of:

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

Output: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/iKJfptf2)

Note: Not sure if this is relevant, but my second monitor was also not being detected. I fixed this by disabling secure boot. The problem with the long boot times was however also present before disabling secure boot.

Comment: Some things to reveiw: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster  What brand/model system? What video card/chip?

Comment: Thanks, i'll take a look. My specs are: Ryzen 7 3700X, 32Gb RAM, RTX 2080 super.

Comment: Have you installed the correct nVidia driver from the Ubuntu repository? #What is installed
`dkms status`

Comment: [Result](https://pastebin.com/niH2qHHX) of ```dkms status```.

There seems to be a newer driver but 'Software & Update' says that the recommended driver is being used.

Comment: What is openafs? And it only is installed in newest kernel, so something new you installed? And then does it boot quicker with old kernel?

Comment: It is an open source implementation of afs file system. I installed it a couple of weeks ago, so before i started having this issue.

Comment: I think I will try to install Ubuntu 22.04 and see if it boots faster. If it does I’ll just copy my data

Answer (score 2):

After manually re-installing GRUB, you should check that the EFI UUID has been updated in your /etc/fstab. To display it, run `cat /etc/fstab`. The line for EFI should look like :

```
UUID=XXXX-XXXX  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
```

Replace XXXX-XXXX with the correct UUID, that you can display with command `lsblk -o name,fstype,size,label,mountpoint,uuid`. You should have something like :

```
sdb                238,5G                        
├─sdb1      vfat     512M             /boot/efi  XXXX-XXXX
└─sdb2      ext4     238G             /          12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012
```

After updating /etc/fstab, you can check that everything is fine by running `sudo mount -a`. No errors should be reported. Hope this helps :).