# How to improve performance if 20.04 is laggy, slow, and unresponsive?

Tags: 20.04

My Ubuntu installation is so laggy and unresponsive. Firefox takes 10 seconds to start. Thunderbird takes 20 seconds or more.

I frequently have to hard restart.

I'm about to stop using Ubuntu if I can't improve performance.

I have an Asus X555 laptop and it has run beautifully for years. It has an i3-5010u CPU with Mesa Intel HD graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)

I use X11 windowing and GNOME 3.36.8.

`free -h`:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          3.7Gi       1.7Gi       180Mi       380Mi       1.9Gi       1.4Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi       1.0Mi       2.0Gi
```

`df -h | grep -v loop`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           383M  2.1M  381M   1% /run
/dev/sda2       457G   83G  351G  20% /
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       511M  5.3M  506M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs           383M   64K  383M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdf1        30G   18G   13G  58% /media/dadio/88DE-2F612
/dev/sdc1        30G   17G   13G  58% /media/dadio/Tig's window
/dev/sdg1       932G  685G  248G  74% /media/dadio/SciFanAct
/dev/sdb1       1.9T  725G  1.2T  39% /media/dadio/SciFi
/dev/sdd1       2.8T  2.7T  110G  97% /media/dadio/3TB
/dev/sde2       932G  869G   64G  94% /media/dadio/3D9F84A836F389F8
/dev/sde1       932G  926G  5.8G 100% /media/dadio/TOSHIBA EXT
```

Comment: How much RAM/swap/disk space do you have? [Edit] your Question and show `free -h;df -h | grep -v loop`. While we are here to help, your threat to "bail out" has no value. If some other OS solves your problem, use it.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm sorry - I'm trying to format the table but it's just one big chunk.

Comment: If any of the other mounts are NTFS, that can slow things down. Make sure Windows fast start up is off, as updates turn it back on. Some things to review: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Comment: Full drives can also slow down systems.  You might want to see about freeing up space on your external Toshiba drive.

Comment: 4GB of RAM is on the low end. In fact the minimum requirements of Ubuntu Desktop recommend 4GB. This does not leave a lot of resources for RAM heavy applications like a web browser. As time has passed, webpages and applications have demanded more and more RAM, which can result in slower performance with aging or lower spec hardware. You may get better performance installing Xubuntu or Lubuntu as these official flavours of Ubuntu have desktop environments that are less taxing on resources, especially RAM.

Comment: Thank you folks for your replies - I will run through the above suggestions and see.