# Ubuntu 22.04 taking long boot time even on SSD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, ssd, 22.04

I've recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a new SSD, but it is taking around 30 seconds to boot up. I've seen people booting up their Ubuntu system within 15 seconds.

So, how can I improve the boot time further?

**Device Information:**

- Model: HP 15-da0077tx
- RAM: 8GB
- SSD: Crucial p2 500 GB NVME
- CPU: Intel Core i5 8th Gen

Currently, I have a dual boot on SSD, with Windows 10. I also have an older version of Ubuntu on my HDD.

**Outputs:**

```
devansh@Dev:~$ systemd-analyze 
Startup finished in 6.113s (firmware) + 2.286s (loader) + 2.682s (kernel) + 14.853s (userspace) = 25.934s 
graphical.target reached after 14.837s in userspace
```

```
devansh@Dev:~$ systemd-analyze blame
13.603s plymouth-quit-wait.service
  456ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
  447ms udisks2.service
  438ms systemd-resolved.service
  393ms systemd-oomd.service
  312ms systemd-timesyncd.service
  307ms dev-nvme0n1p5.device
  209ms networkd-dispatcher.service
  179ms apparmor.service
  177ms systemd-logind.service
  151ms power-profiles-daemon.service
  144ms switcheroo-control.service
  134ms systemd-journal-flush.service
  134ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
  133ms e2scrub_reap.service
```

```
devansh@Dev:~$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @14.837s
└─multi-user.target @14.837s
  └─plymouth-quit-wait.service @1.234s +13.603s
    └─systemd-user-sessions.service @1.225s +5ms
      └─network.target @1.220s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1.141s +77ms
          └─dbus.service @1.135s
            └─basic.target @1.128s
              └─sockets.target @1.128s
                └─uuidd.socket @1.128s
                  └─sysinit.target @1.124s
                    └─systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service @3.911s +456ms
```

Please let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: Some settings to review: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster Do you have a UUID that is now invalid, as if you reinstall & have new UUID for swap but fstab has old UUID?  Have you updated UEFI and updated SSD firmware?

Comment: @oldfred All the UUIDs are valid and correct, and the drivers and SSD firmware are also updated, still, it takes around 25-30 seconds to boot up.

Comment: Since plymouth seems to be your longest issue, did you try the setting change in grub from quiet splash to noplymouth as shown in link in first comment.