# How to reduce Ubuntu boot time?

Tags: boot, mount, fstab

I am new to Ubuntu 20. Please check my fstab screenshot and let me know if any changes are needed. When I log in to my laptop, it takes 1 min to show the Ubuntu logo and after that it takes 2 minutes to complete the boot. I'm also not sure how my swap is 16 GB and how can I change it back to 8 GB.

[image: screenshot of fstab]

Comment: Try running `systemd-analyze blame`.

Comment: adding some of the systemd-analyze blame output: 40.084s plymouth-quit-wait.service 21.102s snapd.service 17.834s dev-sda6.device  13.863s systemd-journal-flush.service   13.771s winbind.service    12.629s NetworkManager-wait-online.service    10.104s networkd-dispatcher.service        9.733s dev-loop18.device       9.593s udisks2.service

Comment: Post blame in question. Review these settings and additional settings in the links. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster I do prefer to create a mount point like /mnt/data or /mnt/photo, rather than use UUID. And then use that in fstab. (but will not change boot time)  I do not remember which UUID is which when I have multiple mounts in /mnt. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: Ubuntu 20?   So this is a Ubuntu Core 20 system? and not a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system?   Ubuntu has both *year* (20) & *year.month* (20.04) products which are different in some respects so please be precise with details.  Ubuntu Core 20?

Comment: From your output: Investigate why sda6 is taking 13.863s to mount. Investigate why NetworkManager is taking 12.629s to get a working network connection. Honestly, about two minutes from a cold-boot to a working desktop seems average for typical users on normal hardware. Ultra-geeks on top-end hardware can cold-boot in under 30 seconds, but it takes them days of tweaking and thousands of dollars in hardware to get there.

Comment: Not quite as bad as user535733 suggests. Main upgrade is an SSD or NVMe drive. NVMe is more expensive & faster, but SSD is still vary fast. For booting it does not have to be large as you can still use HDD for data. My 2014 z97 build with 120GB SSD needing fewer drivers is almost as fast as my 2016 500GB NVMe x170 build, that I posted boot time in link in my comment above of "graphical.target reached after 5.155s in userspace"