# Ubuntu 22.04 takes 2.5 minutes to login (not BOOT)

Tags: login, 22.04

I updated from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 and login went up from almost instantly in Ubuntu 20 to 2.5 minutes in Ubuntu 22!!!

Booting takes longer as well (appr. 50 secs.) Normally all start-up text races by, but now the following text stays on screen for about 20 secs.

```
Running /scripts/local-premount
```

It's the user login that takes 2:15 where only my backdrop is visible.

I have a Asus P8Z77-V MB (some 10 yrs old). Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3225 CPU @ 3.30GHz

Memory 16066MB (3188MB used)

Kernel Linux 5.15.0-37-generic (x86_64) Version #39-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 1 19:16:45 UTC 2022

C Library GNU C Library / (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.35-0ubuntu3) 2.35

Distribution Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Mesa Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2) Version 3.1 Mesa 22.0.1

I wanted to check logs, but don't know which and what to look for.

No NVidia card.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

## EDIT1

During 1st upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 the installer stopped because I didn't have enough space on my / (root) partion (30GB).

I started a Live Linux version from an USB stick and used Gparted to resize the Ext4 root partition with an extra 30 GB. This went all without problems and so did the following update to 22.04.

I have the following partitions on my 128 GB SSD:

sda1  : fat32 /boot/efi    190MB

sda2  : ext4  /boot        572MB

sda3  : ext4  /            58.59GB  (was appr. 30GB before resizing)

Furthermore 2 small data partitions:

sda4 : ext4 LUKS encrypted

sda5 : ext4 data

My home directory is on a 1TB standard harddrive (sdb)

Below I've included output from system-analyze

```
$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 2.717s (firmware) + 4.301s (loader) + 34.923s (kernel) + 6.285s (userspace) = 48.228s 
graphical.target reached after 6.278s in userspace

$ systemd-analyze blame
3.579s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
1.531s snapd.service
1.163s dev-sda3.device
 998ms udisks2.service
 940ms dev-loop12.device
 939ms dev-loop13.device
 939ms dev-loop11.device
 939ms dev-loop10.device
 935ms dev-loop8.device
 935ms dev-loop9.device
 933ms dev-loop15.device
 929ms dev-loop14.device
 829ms blueman-mechanism.service
 762ms dev-loop1.device
 761ms dev-loop4.device
 760ms dev-loop5.device
 760ms dev-loop7.device
 742ms dev-loop3.device
 730ms dev-loop6.device
 710ms dev-loop2.device
 687ms dev-loop0.device
 672ms snapd.seeded.service
 626ms smartmontools.service
 574ms cups.service
 543ms user@1000.service
 502ms accounts-daemon.service
 463ms networkd-dispatcher.service
 421ms ModemManager.service
 290ms systemd-resolved.service
 260ms polkit.service
 258ms systemd-journal-flush.service
 242ms NetworkManager.service
 242ms avahi-daemon.service
 238ms systemd-timesyncd.service
 203ms nginx.service
 190ms systemd-rfkill.service
 190ms gpu-manager.service
 163ms thermald.service
 160ms apparmor.service
 159ms wpa_supplicant.service
 159ms systemd-logind.service
 156ms e2scrub_reap.service
 150ms apport.service
 149ms secureboot-db.service
 141ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
 135ms systemd-udevd.service
 133ms grub-common.service
 127ms colord.service
 121ms snapd.apparmor.service
 119ms alsa-restore.service
 108ms rsyslog.service
 107ms resolvconf-pull-resolved.service
 105ms systemd-fsck@dev-mapper-fedora\x2dhome.service
 104ms systemd-journald.service
 104ms keyboard-setup.service
 102ms lightdm.service
 100ms upower.service
  86ms lm-sensors.service
  85ms lvm2-monitor.service
  82ms lvm2-pvscan@8:18.service
  82ms systemd-modules-load.service
  73ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
  73ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
  72ms dev-mqueue.mount
  72ms dev-hugepages.mount
  69ms modprobe@fuse.service
  67ms kmod-static-nodes.service
  65ms modprobe@drm.service
  65ms modprobe@configfs.service
  65ms snap-bare-5.mount
  64ms virtualbox.service
  62ms WiLiShare.mount
  62ms snap-chromium-2000.mount
```

Comment: I'd first start with creating a new login and seeing if the problem exists with that login.  If it does *not*, then that might mean that there is some problem with your configuration files that are read when you login with your original ID.  My solution is usually to erase them all -- because I don't have the patience to find out which one is the cause...  But you can could try figuring out what's causing it.

Comment: @Ray That did not work. I made a new account/user, logged out of my own account and logged in with the new account. Same story: 2min 15 seconds waiting...

Comment: To confirm boot. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair But issue may be after grub loads. Post: `systemd-analyze` and first page of: `systemd-analyze blame` Review these settings: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Comment: @oldfred Your remarks are a bit cryptic for noob, but I think I have the info you asked for. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tC5WMMQ6w6/ I also editted my question to add info + systemd-analyze output. Thanks for your time

Comment: It says you get to desktop in 6 sec. Not sure why kernel takes as long as it does, but not familiar with LVM/encryption which may be part of it. You can go thru settings in link in previous comment and maybe improve things slightly. Also mounting NTFS is always a bit slower, since Microsoft format You may want to add noatime to partitions mount in fstab for those on SSD. NTFS example: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2420861&p=13865822#post13865822

Comment: @oldfred The first time login after upgrading, the encrypted partition wasn't there yet, but the long wait was there. So that can't be the problem. Yes I noticed the various tweeks, but they don't seem substantial (3 sec. for wait for network etc)

Comment: So is the real question then, why does it take so long to decrypt my encrypted /home partition (or /)? I do not know encryption nor LVM. I might suggest that as a new question, so those that know encryption can offer answers.

Comment: @oldfred No, the question is NOT about encrypting, because the slow login also happened before I made this encrypted directory. When I mount this partition, it opens within seconds, no problem there.

Comment: From Windows did you run chkdsk on the NTFS?

Comment: Just saw in another thread a comment on UEFI settings. It reminded me that one of the first settings I change is to turn off network boot. Never will use it and do not want UEFI looking for network.

Comment: Windows can not check a disk connected to a network is the msg from chkdsk, because I use the NTFS partition in Virtualbox...

Comment: I just had this, and it turned out that it was happening because my monitor was plugged into the motherboard HDMI out rather than the GPU HDMI out.

After swapping the cable, the minutes-long hang after logging in disappeared.