# Boot is too slow after deleting and adding swapfile

Tags: boot, suspend, swap

I have 8GB memory and was experiencing slowness when having multiple apps open, so I decided to increase the swap from 2GB to 8GB. I did the following:

- deleted the swap partition
- created and enabled a swap file in the main partition
- removed the UUID of the partition from /etc/fstab and added the path to the swap file
- rebooted

It worked as I tested opening more apps than I would before and I didn't notice any freezing. But, my boot time went from ~15sec to ~46sec and the following error is shown for ~40sec

```
[ 0.1061511 x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
[ 0.1822951 ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PC10.12C2.TPDOJ, AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
[ 0.1823071 ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/ps object-220)
[ 0.182343] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PC10.12C3.T PL11, AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
[ 0.1823491 ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210730/ps object-220)
[ 0.621220] integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device /dev/nume0n1p6: clean, 893934/6250496 files, 17331878/24999936 blocks
```

Comment: Adding swap space won't give you any speed.

Comment: Check your fstab file, or include it in your question

Comment: How did you create the swap file (which tool and/or commands did you use)?

Comment: Check if this file has old UUID:  this if swap partition reformatted:
 cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume You also may not have it. Some issues to review if slow boot & also links to more solutions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster