# Desktop with Ubunu 22.04 has both sda and nvme0n1 disk partitions

Tags: partitioning, 22.04

```
loop17        7:17   0 105.5M  1 loop /snap/slack/64
sda           8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sda1        8:1    0   512M  0 part
└─sda2        8:2    0   1.8T  0 part
sr0          11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
nvme0n1     259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 953.4G  0 part /
```

I got new desktop HP Pavilion Desktop P01-2xxx 11h Gen Intel Core i7 + AMD@Radeon rx 550 which came wih windows 11. I had to go through trials and errors to wipe out the windows 11 and install ubuntu. Currently I have Ubuntu 22.04LTS / GNome: 42.2 but my desktop performs really slow and few app start to take over 100% of cpu usage...

While trying to track down the issue, I checked I have both sda and nvme0n1 disk partitioned - could this be a potential cause of bad performance? I am willing to wipe out / factory reset my desktop and set it up over again if it can restore normal performance. Any advice on this? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Some settings to review & links to more info. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means your laptop has both a HDD and an NVME SSD.

It shouldn't cause performance problems.

Comment: Thanks :) It seems that wasn't the issue but the real issue is that my desktop only uses single processor when it should have 8 processor core..