# Very slow boot speed in Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, kubuntu, 22.04, snap, docker

I have installed a fresh vanilla Kubuntu 22.04.1 and after a few days it has suddenly become very slow.

The result of `systemd-analyze critical-chain` is as follows:

```
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @2min 46.588s
└─multi-user.target @2min 46.588s
  └─docker.service @2min 35.488s +11.099s
    └─network-online.target @2min 35.451s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @2min 14.648s +20.802s
        └─NetworkManager.service @2min 14.118s +489ms
          └─dbus.service @2min 14.115s
            └─basic.target @2min 14.096s
              └─sockets.target @2min 14.096s
                └─snapd.socket @2min 14.094s +1ms
                  └─sysinit.target @2min 14.057s
                    └─snapd.apparmor.service @2min 13.778s +279ms
                      └─apparmor.service @2min 13.344s +400ms
                        └─local-fs.target @2min 13.320s
                          └─run-snapd-ns-cups.mnt.mount @2min 17.898s
                            └─run-snapd-ns.mount @2min 17.533s
                              └─local-fs-pre.target @1min 50.253s
                                └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service @1min 38.311s +11.941s
                                  └─systemd-sysusers.service @1min 27.128s +11.163s
                                    └─systemd-remount-fs.service @1min 24.213s +2.856s
                                      └─systemd-journald.socket @1min 22.191s
                                        └─-.mount @1min 22.154s
                                          └─-.slice @1min 22.154s
```

This is the distro I'm using.

```bash
$ cat /etc/*-release

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy

$ uname -a

Linux $MACHINE_NAME 5.15.0-53-generic #59-Ubuntu SMP Mon Oct 17 18:53:30 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The OS has suddenly become very slow. It was not slow at all the last time I used it, and it boot like a charm. I use an SSD drive.

Edit: the output of `systemd-analyze blame`:

```bash
$ systemd-analyze blame

48.753s dev-sda2.device
48.552s mullvad-early-boot-blocking.service
45.814s systemd-journal-flush.service
22.991s systemd-sysctl.service
20.802s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
19.169s systemd-modules-load.service
14.611s snap-bare-5.mount
14.023s snap-chromium-2188.mount
13.496s snap-chromium-2193.mount
12.256s snap-core18-2620.mount
11.941s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
11.163s systemd-sysusers.service
11.099s docker.service
10.740s snap-core20-1587.mount
10.143s systemd-random-seed.service
10.064s snap-core20-1695.mount
 9.893s systemd-udev-trigger.service
 9.571s keyboard-setup.service
 8.932s snap-core22-310.mount
 7.580s snap-cups-836.mount
 7.110s dev-loop14.device
 7.106s dev-loop10.device
 7.105s dev-loop13.device
 7.072s dev-loop9.device
 7.071s dev-loop12.device
 7.068s dev-loop11.device
 6.935s dev-loop15.device
 6.924s dev-loop8.device
 6.846s dev-loop0.device
 6.845s dev-loop1.device
 6.840s dev-loop6.device
 6.838s dev-loop4.device
 6.836s dev-loop5.device
 6.835s dev-loop3.device
 6.835s dev-loop7.device
 6.739s dev-loop2.device
 6.436s snap-discord-145.mount
 6.382s dev-loop17.device
 6.286s dev-loop16.device
 6.186s systemd-udevd.service
 5.608s snap-firefox-1635.mount
 5.545s swapfile.swap
 4.616s systemd-journald.service
 4.569s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-77.mount
 3.561s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-112.mount
 3.268s snapd.service
 3.173s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-119.mount
 3.104s bolt.service
 2.856s systemd-remount-fs.service
 2.565s snap-gnome\x2d42\x2d2204-29.mount
 2.531s kerneloops.service
 2.193s containerd.service
 2.183s dev-hugepages.mount
 2.181s dev-mqueue.mount
 2.178s sys-kernel-debug.mount
 2.175s sys-kernel-tracing.mount
 1.936s kmod-static-nodes.service
 1.935s modprobe@configfs.service
 1.934s modprobe@drm.service
 1.933s modprobe@fuse.service
 1.770s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1535.mount
 1.280s networkd-dispatcher.service
 1.111s udisks2.service
 1.050s accounts-daemon.service
 1.028s snap-snapd-17336.mount
 1.024s snap-slack-67.mount
 1.015s apt-daily.service
  928ms ModemManager.service
  740ms snap-snapd-17576.mount
  611ms cups.service
  555ms polkit.service
  553ms power-profiles-daemon.service
  495ms bluetooth.service
  495ms avahi-daemon.service
  489ms NetworkManager.service
  448ms thermald.service
  446ms systemd-logind.service
  444ms systemd-resolved.service
  429ms wpa_supplicant.service
  400ms apparmor.service
  363ms gpu-manager.service
  356ms smartmontools.service
  352ms secureboot-db.service
  348ms ssh.service
  279ms e2scrub_reap.service
  279ms snapd.apparmor.service
  275ms apport.service
  265ms rsyslog.service
  261ms systemd-timesyncd.service
  251ms upower.service
  225ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
  224ms sys-kernel-config.mount
  222ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
  218ms ua-timer.service
  181ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
  175ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-307A\x2d2082.service
  135ms packagekit.service
  121ms user@1000.service
  102ms snapd.seeded.service
  101ms plymouth-start.service
   92ms systemd-rfkill.service
   82ms alsa-restore.service
   72ms plymouth-quit.service
   70ms setvtrgb.service
   64ms modprobe@chromeos_pstore.service
   62ms fwupd-refresh.service
   59ms boot-efi.mount
   44ms systemd-backlight@leds:tpacpi::kbd_backlight.service
   40ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
   40ms plymouth-read-write.service
   40ms grub-initrd-fallback.service
   37ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
   33ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
   33ms ufw.service
   26ms sddm.service
   19ms systemd-user-sessions.service
   18ms grub-common.service
   15ms systemd-update-utmp.service
   12ms console-setup.service
    9ms modprobe@efi_pstore.service
    8ms rtkit-daemon.service
    7ms modprobe@pstore_blk.service
    6ms modprobe@pstore_zone.service
    4ms modprobe@ramoops.service
    4ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
    2ms docker.socket
    1ms snapd.socket
```

The output of `blkid` and `lsblk`:

```bash
$blkid

/dev/sda2: UUID="2db45c19-bd8f-4faa-ab82-777ee377b5b7" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="238144ae-ec8d-4c17-a2de-19497332f33a"

$lsblk

NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0    7:0    0 145.5M  1 loop /snap/chromium/2188
loop1    7:1    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop2    7:2    0 145.3M  1 loop /snap/chromium/2193
loop3    7:3    0  55.6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2620
loop4    7:4    0    62M  1 loop /snap/core20/1587
loop5    7:5    0  63.2M  1 loop /snap/core20/1695
loop6    7:6    0  72.8M  1 loop /snap/core22/310
loop7    7:7    0  55.1M  1 loop /snap/cups/836
loop8    7:8    0  81.4M  1 loop /snap/discord/145
loop9    7:9    0 163.3M  1 loop /snap/firefox/1635
loop10   7:10   0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77
loop11   7:11   0 400.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/112
loop12   7:12   0 346.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119
loop13   7:13   0 414.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-42-2204/29
loop14   7:14   0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop15   7:15   0 112.6M  1 loop /snap/slack/67
loop16   7:16   0    48M  1 loop /snap/snapd/17336
loop17   7:17   0  49.6M  1 loop /snap/snapd/17576
sda      8:0    0 476.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2   8:2    0 476.4G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   1     0B  0 disk
```

EDIT2: I have attached a screenshot of the boot screen, apparently `containerd`, `docker engine` and `snapd` are failing in the boot screen for whatever reason.

[image: Boot Screen]

EDIT3: So after completely removing `docker` and `containerd` from my system, the issue still persists.

```bash
$systemd-analyze critical-chain
graphical.target @1min 49.545s
└─multi-user.target @1min 49.544s
  └─snapd.seeded.service @1min 49.115s +428ms
    └─snapd.service @26.943s +1min 22.164s
      └─basic.target @26.858s
        └─sockets.target @26.858s
          └─snapd.socket @26.857s +570us
            └─sysinit.target @26.853s
              └─snapd.apparmor.service @26.524s +328ms
                └─apparmor.service @14.232s +12.289s
                  └─local-fs.target @14.231s
                    └─run-snapd-ns.mount @1min 48.407s
                      └─local-fs-pre.target @1.001s
                        └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service @948ms +52ms
                          └─systemd-sysusers.service @907ms +39ms
                            └─systemd-remount-fs.service @856ms +49ms
                              └─systemd-journald.socket @827ms
                                └─system.slice @823ms
                                  └─-.slice @823ms
```

Comment: Add `$ systemd-analyze blame` to your post, might be interesting, easier to check.

Comment: Some settings to review. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster But if ok before, what changed. It looks like a video issue? What brand/model system and what video. Did you (or a back ground task) update UEFI and revert to defaults. You may want to check settings.

Comment: How are you mounting old laptop. If still seen as something to remount on boot, but unplugged, then it has to timeout on searching for a missing mount.

Comment: @oldfred sorry I deleted my prev comment by accident. I'm using LAN via an access point and rsyncing my files.

Comment: So on reboot is network not up and you are trying to mount it. Then it has to time out. Sometimes the boot with SSD, now is so fast that it loads before everything is available. I have seen where others have to add a script that runs just after or at end of boot to get some devices to work correctly. What is this device? "48.753s dev-sda2.device"

Comment: @oldfred It was just one time. I transferred my files using a LAN connection and then connected to my default network. dev-sda2 is apparently my main hard drive. My ssd drive. I'm updating the question again.

Comment: It seems "mullvad-early-boot-blocking" perhaps prevents network coming up before Mullvad, but you need networking to connect your "sda2" so there's a logical conflict there?

Comment: Perhaps this Mullvad logging issue applies, https://forum.manjaro.org/t/failed-to-start-mullvad-early-boot-network-blocker/126152/11?

Comment: @pbhj Hi again. I've disabled the mullvad service but the problem still persists. The issue is apparenlty from docker and containerd. I've attached a picture of my boot error.

Comment: @pbhj so I still have this issue after removing docker and containerd completely. The boot time is very slow, and my disk has also become very slow to use after boot.