# swap partition exists but not usable

Tags: boot, partitioning, swap

I resized the swap partition but I guess I did something wrong. Ubuntu boot time is now between 2-3 minutes. After checking the swap partition, I saw it's the right size in gParted but reads 0Gb when I checked it in free -h. In gParted I right-clicked on it then chose "swapon" but it had no effect. What can I do?

Comment: Did your changes, change the UUID of swap? You need to compare UUID in fstab with UUID of swap partition. `cat /etc/fstab` and `lsblk -f` if different update fstab.

Comment: oldfred, thanks. They were different so I updated it then verified to be sure. One thing  though, the main ubuntu ext4 partition displays "errors=remount-ro 0  1" next to it. I don't know how to deal with this. The beginning of the boot time is still very long, the part with the command lines on black screen, but once the ubuntu logo appears, all goes as fast as before.

Comment: Try the ESC key at the delay and see if you get a screen of progress messaegs -- see the last one.  It might the last one that succeeded, or the one with a timeout countdown. Also, maybe mkswap on the new swap partition might help.

Comment: @ubfan1 thanks for your help, I'll keep you posted. BTW, the swap file is now on and the 4Gb I assigned appear as available under free -h. I just need to fix the delay problem.

Comment: The errors=remount is standard and should not be changed. If you have to run fsck because of errors, it need to be read only (ro). Some things to review if boot is slow. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Comment: Delay can be network connectivity for all sorts of reasons, including network discs, or trying to use IPv6 on a network or ISP that doesn't support it. Log file viewer is easier `journalctl -b` should be a starting point

Comment: Problem solved, sadly not sure how. After I fixed the UID mismatch I rebooted and had that delay while in black screen. I did nothing else then left the studio with the computer in lock mode. I just got back and rebooted again and to my surprise all is like before. So I'm guessing it could be for one of the reasons @Crighton brought up.