# Ubuntu takes 2-3 minutes to boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia

My Ubuntu installation is booting slowly.

```
Specs:
OS: Ubuntu 22.10 in dual boot configuration with Windows 11
Architecture (OS type): 64-bit
GNOME Version: 42.1
Windowing System: X11
Motherboard (hardware model): Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. B660 DS3H AC DDR4-Y1
Memory: 16 GiB (mixed models)
CPU (processor): 12th Gen Intel® Core™ i3-12100F × 8
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650
Disk Capacity: System says: 500.1 GB | Actual capacity: 4 TB
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Can you please [edit] the question and post the outputs of the commands `systemd-analyze`, `systemd-analyze blame` and `systemd-analyze critical-chain`? Please copy paste the outputs within the question as texts, and don't post a screenshot of the terminal outputs.

Comment: This will show many details of your install. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  And some things to review that may slow boot. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster