# Long booting time

Tags: boot

Hello I am a Linux newbie,
I installed Kubuntu today and now my laptop's boot take something like 10s, when using windows 11 it took 1,5s. Can I fix this problem somehow?

Also what is worth mention I think that my computer is booting like 2 times? The msi logo appear 2-3 times before showing kubuntu interface.

```
anti@anti-msi:~$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 2.379s (kernel) + 7.564s (userspace) = 9.943s 
graphical.target reached after 7.557s in userspace

anti@anti-msi:~$ systemd-analyze blame
6.408s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 632ms gpu-manager.service
 537ms systemd-logind.service
 300ms snapd.service
 290ms modprobe@chromeos_pstore.service
 239ms dev-nvme0n1p2.device
 222ms networkd-dispatcher.service
 217ms accounts-daemon.service
 201ms upower.service
 198ms systemd-resolved.service
 186ms bluetooth.service
 183ms boot-efi.mount
 170ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
 156ms power-profiles-daemon.service
 134ms dev-loop4.device
 133ms e2scrub_reap.service
 133ms dev-loop5.device
 131ms dev-loop10.device
 130ms dev-loop11.device
 130ms snapd.apparmor.service
 129ms dev-loop9.device
 129ms dev-loop7.device
 129ms systemd-timesyncd.service
 128ms dev-loop0.device
 128ms dev-loop8.device
 128ms udisks2.service
 124ms dev-loop12.device
 124ms dev-loop3.device
 122ms dev-loop2.device
 119ms dev-loop6.device
 108ms ModemManager.service
 107ms apparmor.service
 107ms dev-loop1.device
 106ms systemd-journal-flush.service
  95ms NetworkManager.service
  95ms snapd.seeded.service
  93ms avahi-daemon.service
  87ms polkit.service
  84ms packagekit.service
  82ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
  78ms thermald.service
  76ms wpa_supplicant.service
  74ms systemd-udevd.service
  54ms smartmontools.service
  53ms user@1000.service
  51ms secureboot-db.service
  46ms apport.service
  44ms rsyslog.service
  43ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-37A6\x2dDE91.service
  42ms keyboard-setup.service
  37ms cups.service
  33ms systemd-sysctl.service
  28ms systemd-journald.service
  28ms plymouth-start.service
  27ms systemd-modules-load.service
  21ms plymouth-quit.service
  19ms snap-bare-5.mount
  18ms snap-core-14447.mount
  17ms snap-core20-1587.mount
  17ms snap-core20-1822.mount
  16ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
  15ms snap-core22-504.mount
  15ms dev-hugepages.mount
  15ms dev-mqueue.mount
  15ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
  14ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
  13ms snap-firefox-1635.mount
  13ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
  12ms snap-gedit-664.mount
  12ms plymouth-read-write.service
  12ms kmod-static-nodes.service
  12ms kerneloops.service
  12ms systemd-sysusers.service
  12ms modprobe@drm.service
  11ms modprobe@configfs.service
  11ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-112.mount
  11ms modprobe@fuse.service
  10ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-119.mount
  10ms snap-gnome\x2d42\x2d2204-56.mount
   9ms systemd-random-seed.service
   9ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
   8ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
   7ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1535.mount
   7ms grub-common.service
   6ms snap-notepadqq-855.mount
   6ms systemd-remount-fs.service
   6ms grub-initrd-fallback.service
   6ms snap-snapd-17950.mount
   6ms alsa-restore.service
   5ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
   5ms systemd-user-sessions.service
   4ms systemd-rfkill.service
   4ms console-setup.service
   4ms sddm.service
   3ms swapfile.swap
   3ms systemd-update-utmp.service
   3ms ufw.service
   3ms nvidia-persistenced.service
   2ms rtkit-daemon.service
   2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
   1ms setvtrgb.service
   1ms modprobe@efi_pstore.service
   1ms sys-kernel-config.mount
   1ms modprobe@pstore_blk.service
   1ms modprobe@pstore_zone.service
   1ms modprobe@ramoops.service
 369us snapd.socket


anti@anti-msi:~$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @7.557s
└─multi-user.target @7.557s
  └─kerneloops.service @7.544s +12ms
    └─network-online.target @7.528s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1.118s +6.408s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1.022s +95ms
          └─dbus.service @1.021s
            └─basic.target @1.014s
              └─sockets.target @1.014s
                └─snapd.socket @1.014s +369us
                  └─sysinit.target @1.011s
                    └─snapd.apparmor.service @881ms +130ms
                      └─apparmor.service @771ms +107ms
                        └─local-fs.target @769ms
                          └─boot-efi.mount @586ms +183ms
                            └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-37A6\x2dDE91.service @541ms +43ms
                              └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-37A6\x2dDE91.device @515ms
```

Comment: Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1454145/edit) and post the full outputs of `systemd-analyze`, `systemd-analyze blame`,  and `systemd-analyze critical-chain`?

Comment: Please format the terminal output properly. This shows how to https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14089/124466

Comment: Your release details are also helpful

Comment: I think "can I make my system boot faster" is a valid question, and it might require reducing things that are being loaded.  But, comparing KUbuntu with Windows 11 and using the latter as a benchmark is probably not a good idea.  They're two different OS'.  The latter of which might start up quickly, but defer the loading of other programs until after the user logs in (for example).  In other words, it may not be something that is "broken".

Comment: You're not really comparing apples with apples. Windows uses hybrid suspend. So you're not actually counting full boot time, just the time it takes to wake from suspend. Linux can do this too, but hybrid suspend can be a little unreliable on Linux, so it's often disabled. Worth looking into, if those 8.5s are valuable to you ;)

Comment: Some settings you can review, if you want. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Comment: how i can edit my post so command lines will be better shown

Comment: Select the text and click the `{}` icon to format. But 10s is OK for a real boot. Windows boots longer. Choose restart in Windows and you'll be able to compare comparable.

Answer (score 0):

10 seconds for a real boot time is good. I can't see it is a "problem". If you turn your laptop off and on frequently, you can use suspend instead of shut down. If you don't do it often, 10s wait is not really long.

My system boots in 12s, and I don't consider it "slow".

Windows doesn't really boot in 1.5s. It is using Fast Boot that is hibernation. If you restart Windows, you'll see that it boots much slower than Ubuntu.

You can also enable hibernation, or hybrid-sleep in Ubuntu. But on some hardware it may not properly work. That's why it is disabled by default.

Also it is OK that a vendor logo appears a few times.

Comment: ok thank you, i got one more question, i have read that sometimes gpu_manager can has bug that rewrite something every time while booting, how can i check if it doesnt appear in my cimputer

Comment: I've never heard about either `gpu_manager` or this type of problem.