# Why is Ubuntu booting slower if I disable quiet boot?

Tags: boot, grub2, 22.04

I don't really like quiet boot, because it shows only a splash screen, which is not too informative. To increase verbosity, i always remove `quiet` and `splash` from `/etc/default/grub` to be able to see kernel boot process:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`

However I noticed that disabling quiet boot slows down the booting process:

- Without quiet boot: ~40 sec
- With quiet boot: ~30 sec

What causes this phenomenon?

*(System: Kubuntu 22.04 LTS)*

Comment: I add noplymounth & remove quiet splash. Some other settings to review. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster Of course adding a SSD speeds up boot a lot.