# Very slow first logging after a boot at ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, kernel, 22.04, logging

## Description

I am attempting to resolve the issue of an extremely slow login process following the boot on my Ubuntu 22.04 system. While the booting time is relatively fast and does not pose any issues, logging in as a user for the first time is taking several minutes to complete the process.  Even after successfully logging in, it takes a while for the desktop to fully load and become usable.

Has anyone else experienced a similar issue on **Ubuntu 22.04**, and if so, do you know of any potential solutions?

## Logs

### uname output

```
$ uname -r
5.19.0-38-generic
```

### systemd-analyze output

```
$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 9.888s (firmware) + 5.299s (loader) + 51.270s (kernel) + 20.436s (userspace) = 1min 26.896s 
graphical.target reached after 20.397s in userspace
```

### systemd-analyze critical-chain output

```
$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @20.397s
└─multi-user.target @20.396s
  └─plymouth-quit-wait.service @2.518s +17.875s
    └─systemd-user-sessions.service @2.449s +44ms
      └─nss-user-lookup.target @2.395s
        └─sssd.service @1.468s +925ms
          └─basic.target @1.422s
            └─sockets.target @1.422s
              └─cups.socket @1.984s
                └─sysinit.target @1.412s
                  └─systemd-backlight@leds:dell::kbd_backlight.service @3.364s +1.263s
                    └─system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice @631ms
                      └─system.slice @176ms
                        └─-.slice @176ms
```

### systemd-analyze blame output

```
$ systemd-analyze blame
17.875s plymouth-quit-wait.service
10.618s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 5.897s snapd.service
 4.929s systemd-rfkill.service
 4.729s fwupd.service
 2.131s logrotate.service
 1.263s systemd-backlight@leds:dell::kbd_backlight.service
 1.151s cups.service
 1.009s dev-mapper-vgubuntu\x2droot.device
.
.
.
```

#Edit#
I updated the kernel version according to this site: https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu/ to the **v6.2.10** and it slightly helped but the logging time is too slow.

## New logs

### uname output

```
$ uname -r
6.2.10-060210-generic
```

### systemd-analyze output

```
$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 10.400s (firmware) + 5.395s (loader) + 17.545s (kernel) + 32.571s (userspace) = 1min 5.912s 
graphical.target reached after 32.512s in userspace
```

### systemd-analyze critical-chain output

```
$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @32.512s
└─multi-user.target @32.511s
  └─plymouth-quit-wait.service @13.856s +18.652s
    └─systemd-user-sessions.service @13.810s +33ms
      └─nss-user-lookup.target @13.708s
        └─sssd.service @12.861s +839ms
          └─basic.target @12.793s
            └─sockets.target @12.793s
              └─snapd.socket @12.767s +25ms
                └─sysinit.target @12.752s
                  └─snapd.apparmor.service @7.875s +4.876s
                    └─apparmor.service @1.147s +6.701s
                      └─local-fs.target @1.108s
                        └─run-snapd-ns-snapd\x2ddesktop\x2dintegration.mnt.mount @31.438s
                          └─run-snapd-ns.mount @29.809s
                            └─swap.target @1.647s
                              └─dev-mapper-vgubuntu\x2dswap_1.swap @1.591s +46ms
                                └─dev-mapper-vgubuntu\x2dswap_1.device @1.572s
```

### systemd-analyze blame output

```
$ systemd-analyze blame
18.652s plymouth-quit-wait.service
16.314s snapd.service
 7.026s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 6.701s apparmor.service
 4.876s snapd.apparmor.service
 4.612s fwupd.service
 1.407s systemd-rfkill.service
 1.369s dev-mapper-vgubuntu\x2droot.device
  995ms cups.service
  865ms dev-loop6.device
  839ms sssd.service
  772ms dev-loop5.device
  769ms dev-loop4.device
  768ms dev-loop3.device
  768ms dev-loop7.device
  767ms dev-loop2.device
  766ms dev-loop1.device
  765ms dev-loop0.device
  713ms user@1000.service
  706ms networkd-dispatcher.service
  669ms udisks2.service
  655ms accounts-daemon.service
  612ms snapd.seeded.service
.
.
.
```

Comment: Some things to review and links for more suggestions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster I did all the same changes in my 22.04 when I reinstalled.

Comment: Look at your shell's Startup Files (`~/.bashrc` and more, read `man bash`). Check which processes are getting started in `~/.config/autostart/*`.

Comment: You say you are running a 6.2 kernel. There is not a current version of Ubuntu using that as a supported kernel. Why are you using this test kernel?