# New Ubuntu install is laggy

Tags: system-installation

Installing Ubuntu 22.04.2.LTS and it is running very slow. When I type it takes about one second per character to type and the cursor lags around the screen.

Before installing if I “try ubuntu” in safe graphics mode using the usb install disk it runs fine, without lag. But as soon as it’s installed on the machine disk the performance tanks. It’s unusable.

Other posts suggested it could be to do with the swapfile, however I checked and it’s hardly being used.

This is my machine:

- Laptop model: Inspiron 16 plus 7620
- BIOS version: dell 1.11.0
- CPU: i7 12700 H
- Graphics: intel iris Xe graphics

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Comment: sorry it's Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS which I got from the ubuntu desktop website. I've corrected the typo in my original post.

Comment: just tried installing fedora and had the same issue :(

Comment: What's your CPU and RAM on the system?

Comment: 16gb of ram and CPU is i7 12700H.

Comment: Is that latest firmware for the UEFI from Dell. And if NVMe drive, do you have latest firmware? That system should not be slow. I have Kubuntu on Dell with 11th Gen Intel & my own Desktop build with 12th gen and neither have issues. I do adjust some settings. Details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster You may need 23.04, just to have newer kernel & drivers since very new system, otherwise best to use the latest LTS version which you have.

Comment: I just Googled your model and I can't easily see an exact release date.  However, the various reviews seem to have been published in late 2022 or early 2023.  Based on that, I'd echo @oldfred's comment and suggest that you try the latest version of Ubuntu.  Then, upgrade to 23.10 when it is released and from 24.04, get back on to an LTS, if you want to use an LTS.

Comment: I installed 23.04 and had the same issue. However....

When I booted in recovery mode and continued onto normal boot everything was fine and running smoothly. Restarted the laptop and it was back to its slow laggy behaviour again.

When continuing with the normal boot from recovery mode I was warned that some of the graphics adapters may not load correctly - given that the machine worked better via this route I'm beginning to think it is a graphics adapter issue.

Comment: I have the same issue with my HP Victus - i5 13500H - RTX4050.
First I thought about the diplay refresh rate which was 144Hz by default. When I change it improved a lot but still it was not smooth like win11. I also tried both Nvidia and Xorg Nouveau drivers but nothing changed. Also I tried Kubuntu, Wayland and X11. Also didn't changed anything.
I still couldn't figure it out why it's improved by the refresh rate change. What is it about. When start it with safe mode without GIU I feel the smooth terminal, not a laggy one in the GUI mode.

Is there any updates on your side?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a Dell Inspiron 16 Plus 7620, Intel core i7, GeForce RTX 3050 Ti. Here is what I did to resolve the issue:

Open a terminal (CTRL + ALT + T)

Run "sudo nano /etc/default/grub"

Change this line:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

To:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.enable_psr=0"

Run "sudo update-grub"

Run "sudo reboot"