# Ubuntu very slow on Dual boot

Tags: boot, drivers, dual-boot, system-installation, performance

I Have recently dual booted Ubuntu on my old windows laptop. But after installation Ubuntu feels very slow. It takes much time to boot and reach to login screen. Opening basic Applications like file manager, Browser and all the other apps takes too much time. Earlier when I was using Windows 10 on the same machine it never felt slow in booting and performing basic operations like surfing web opening applications.

Machine specifications :

processor = Intel Pentium N3710
Ram = DDR3 4GB
storage = 512 (HDD)

Comment: If I were you I would switch to an SSD instead of using an HDD. This can make a huge, very noticeable difference in terms of performance. Also, what version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: You could also use a lighter weight flavor. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie  I use Kubuntu both on new & old systens, it is more of a mid-weight flavor. Some things to review for slow boot: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster & with only 4GB of RAM, do not load a lot of apps into RAM at once. Cache is slow compared to RAM.