# slow booting of xubuntu in virtual box

Tags: boot, virtualbox, xubuntu, plymouth

I installed Xubuntu 22.04 in virtualbox. But takes more than five minutes.
I have given the system plenty of ram, 6 cpus and disk space is half used.

The longest acitve service while booting is:
plymouth-quit-wait.service (4min 59.800s)

with the dependencies:
systemctl list-dependencies --reverse plymouth-quit-wait.service
plymouth-quit-wait.service
● └─multi-user.target
●   └─graphical.target

[image: symstemdAnalyze]

Comment: Not sure what applies or may be additional issues in virtual box, but some things to review: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster