# Boot is very slow

Tags: boot, systemd

Boot is very slow.

systemd-analyze blame:

```
32.737s plymouth-quit-wait.service
15.396s e2scrub_reap.service
11.650s ModemManager.service
11.355s systemd-journal-flush.service
 8.191s dev-sda2.device
 6.844s gdm.service
 6.822s cups.service
 6.350s udisks2.service
 6.118s fwupd.service
 5.591s NetworkManager.service
 5.008s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 3.633s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-d59c95b9\x2db998\x2d4520\x2db2ae\x2d6633707bbdd3.service
 3.424s lvm2-monitor.service
 3.266s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-B30E\x2dA6F5.service
 3.214s accounts-daemon.service
 2.859s power-profiles-daemon.service
 2.791s polkit.service
 2.512s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
 2.359s systemd-modules-load.service
 2.284s geoclue.service
 2.260s systemd-udevd.service
 1.889s systemd-udev-trigger.service
 1.886s systemd-sysusers.service
 1.690s bluetooth.service
 1.689s avahi-daemon.service
 1.648s colord.service
 1.577s keyboard-setup.service
 1.568s networking.service
 1.542s plymouth-start.service
 1.532s switcheroo-control.service
 1.507s dbus.service
 1.447s wpa_supplicant.service
 1.415s systemd-random-seed.service
 1.296s systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
 1.026s dev-disk-by\x2duuid-30b79840\x2d9df5\x2d4183\x2db1c9\x2dfa2b71d898eb.swap
  993ms apparmor.service
  829ms systemd-logind.service
  566ms apt-daily.service
  516ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
  482ms boot-efi.mount
  450ms user@1000.service
  433ms systemd-journald.service
  408ms systemd-rfkill.service
  402ms modprobe@fuse.service
  343ms upower.service
  328ms systemd-update-utmp.service
  285ms systemd-sysctl.service
  281ms systemd-timesyncd.service
  254ms systemd-remount-fs.service
  218ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
  189ms modprobe@configfs.service
  161ms ifupdown-pre.service
  108ms console-setup.service
  107ms plymouth-read-write.service
   97ms systemd-binfmt.service
   85ms rtkit-daemon.service
   79ms dev-hugepages.mount
   76ms dev-mqueue.mount
   72ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
   72ms kmod-static-nodes.service
   69ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
   66ms home.mount
  46ms systemd-user-sessions.service
   38ms modprobe@drm.service
   27ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
   15ms alsa-restore.service
   10ms sys-kernel-config.mount
    8ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
    6ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
    6ms modprobe@dm_mod.service
    4ms modprobe@efi_pstore.service
    3ms modprobe@loop.service
    2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
   96us blk-availability.service
```

Perhaps the problem is that I installed the distribution on the dynamic partition?

Comment: Some settings to review. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster Not familiar with e2scrub, but it looks like it is the e2fsck service for LVM or external drives. Do you have an issue that needs fsck on LVM volumes? https://lore.kernel.org/all/fb05730f-c078-ec94-72d3-83a398f936a7@molgen.mpg.de/

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that I installed the distribution on the dynamic partition?

Comment: Windows dynamic partitions are proprietary to Windows and with new UEFI systems not required. It was a Microsoft work around for the old MBR 4 primary partition limit. But gpt partitioning has a 128 partition soft (changeable) limit. Post this from live installer: `sudo parted -l` & `sudo fdisk -lu`