# 20.04 boot & app load time?

Tags: boot, hard-drive, ssd

I've progressed from 16.04 to 20.04 & I'm happy except boot & app load times have increased with each upgrade. My SW is fully up to date. I have questions:

1. Would a fresh install of 20.04 improve times?
2. Would a change from my HDD to an SSD & fresh install improve times?
   My HDD is a Seagate Barracuda (ST320DM000-1BD14C) with an average seek time of 11ms.
   The SDD would be a Crucial BX500 with a seek time is 0.1ms.
   Thanks in advance, Trevor.

Comment: Generally, SSDs are faster, it is not a secret, so yes, probably.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Has anyone quantified the times for Linux/Ubuntu PCs? Just curious.

Comment: Perhaps someone did, you are more than welcome to use a search engine to find out. I see no merit in such an exercise, as different computers are not made equal, but who knows...

Comment: I upgraded my M.2 SSD to larger NVMe drive. Did not notice a huge improvement like I did when going from HDD to SSD. But these settings also make a large difference and what flavor you boot makes a difference. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster I always do new install, use LTS versions and have two / (root) partitions and alternate install partitions. All data, but not /home is in separate data partition(s).

Comment: Is this question open to other possible causes? Or are your sure that you only want to compare those two solutions?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, I havn't done a fresh install since 16.04 only upgrades. I was simply asking general advice on speed up due to a fresh standard install & HDD to SSD? I have no reason to suspect there is anything wrong requiring troubleshooting. HDD activity during boot is continuous not fragmented.

Answer (score 0):

A fresh install could improve your app load times, but the biggest improvement in boot and app load times would be achieved by changing to a new SSD and installing either Ubuntu 20.04 or the latest LTS version, Ubuntu 22.04, on it.

Comment: OK, thanks. It sounds like a move to SSD makes sense. You mention 22.04, I'd prefer to stick with 20.04 because my peripherals (optical drives, card reader, USB WiFi) & important apps (Asunder & Document-Scanner) work well with 20.04. With the move from HDD to SSD are there any electromechanical issues I should be aware of other than 3.5" vs 2.5"?

Comment: I don't know of any electromechanical issues that you should be aware of, but to be on the safe side you could select the *Try Ubuntu* option of the Ubuntu installer to try Ubuntu in a live session before installing it.