# Ubuntu 20.04 takes too long to display login screen

Tags: boot, 20.04, startup

My Ubuntu 20.04 startup is very slow (I have to wait 43 seconds to have the loader animation and the login screen is reached after 3 minutes and 5 seconds), when I press ESC I can see what makes the startup slow :

[image]

```
$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @2min 56.581s
└─multi-user.target @2min 56.581s
  └─snapd.seeded.service @2min 18.804s +4.297s
    └─snapd.service @1min 41.918s +36.884s
      └─basic.target @1min 41.661s
        └─sockets.target @1min 41.661s
          └─snapd.socket @1min 41.660s +1ms
            └─sysinit.target @1min 41.569s
              └─snapd.apparmor.service @1min 38.168s +3.400s
                └─apparmor.service @1min 35.428s +2.739s
                  └─systemd-journald.socket @5.225s
                    └─-.mount @5.214s
                      └─system.slice @5.214s
                        └─-.slice @5.214s

$ systemd-analyze blame
1min 4.772s plymouth-quit-wait.service
    36.884s snapd.service
    28.212s dev-sda5.device
    23.701s systemd-journal-flush.service
    19.714s dev-loop42.device
    19.475s dev-loop39.device
    19.231s dev-loop43.device
    19.156s dev-loop44.device
    19.067s dev-loop31.device
    18.919s dev-loop30.device
    18.899s dev-loop45.device
    18.664s dev-loop34.device
    18.634s networkd-dispatcher.service
    18.286s vboxdrv.service
    18.196s dev-loop41.device
    17.673s dev-loop40.device
    17.534s dev-loop25.device
    17.533s dev-loop38.device
    17.261s dev-loop37.device
    17.103s dev-loop21.device
    17.060s dev-loop36.device
    17.060s dev-loop28.device
    17.054s dev-loop35.device
    16.123s dev-loop11.device
    15.913s dev-loop24.device
    15.800s dev-loop29.device
    15.796s dev-loop33.device
    15.242s dev-loop32.device
    15.206s dev-loop26.device
    15.204s dev-loop22.device
    14.790s dev-loop23.device
    14.670s dev-loop9.device
    14.484s dev-loop13.device
    13.823s dev-loop20.device
    13.569s dev-loop16.device
    13.400s udisks2.service
    13.268s dev-loop14.device
    12.721s dev-loop27.device
    12.686s accounts-daemon.service
    12.534s dev-loop18.device
    12.303s dev-loop19.device
    11.989s dev-loop12.device
    11.731s dev-loop15.device
    11.353s dev-loop17.device
    11.224s dev-loop10.device
    10.506s ModemManager.service
    10.371s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
    10.299s dev-loop2.device
    10.285s dev-loop7.device
    10.274s dev-loop5.device
     9.945s dev-loop8.device
     9.771s dev-loop1.device
     9.433s NetworkManager.service
     9.180s dev-loop3.device
     9.108s dev-loop4.device
     9.108s dev-loop6.device
     8.705s polkit.service
     7.710s avahi-daemon.service
```

Comment: `snapd.service @1min 41.918s +36.884s`

Comment: @user535733 OK but there's also the /dev/disk/by-uuid/39D9-E87F job that takes too long and I can see that it time-outs and systemd prints : dependency failed for file system check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/39D9-E87F, /boot/efi and Local file systems

Comment: That too. Um, you have not actually asked a question yet.

Comment: Some things to review & possibly change: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Comment: Thank you @oldfred that's what I need