# NVME SSD is slow on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: nvme, 23.10

This is a strange one. On a fresh install of Ubuntu 23.10 (and Desbian 12, Pop os) I'm getting 40MB/s with ssh-benchmark snap, while on my old laptop with a cheap SATA SSD I'm getting 90MB/s.
Any ideas on how to tackle this issue?

EDIT: On manjaro it's around 4500MB/s

Thanks :)

My hardware is Ryzen 7500F, Gigabyte AORUS Gen4 5000E 2TB, 32GB DDR5, RTX 3090.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware to latest available? Some settings that still apply: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Comment: @oldfred UEFI is up to date, how can I update the SSD firmware? There is no info on gigabytes website. Also, I believe the issue comes from Ubuntu because on Manjaro the SSD works as expected.

Comment: Found this right away. https://www.gigabyte.com/SSD/AORUS-Gen4-5000E-SSD-2TB/support#support-dl-utility Do not know if they have an easy way for Linux users. My Samsung NVMe drives have separate ISO like live installer for updates.

Comment: Are you booting under power or booting under battery when you get those readings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was found [HERE](https://superuser.com/questions/610827/identifying-cause-for-really-slow-write-speed-on-ssd-during-install)

Basically the issue is with the `barrier` flag for ext4 under Debian based distros