# Ubuntu running too slow after installing it on my new ssd

Tags: 22.04

I had Ubuntu installed on my HDD earlier the performance was OK, but I wanted to make some improvements, so I got new SSD and installed Ubuntu on that SSD. Ever since I installed Ubuntu on my SSD the performance got worse, boot time is about 24 minutes and applications take a minimum of 4 minutes to load. Due to this problem I reinstalled it about 4 times, but the problem persists. After installation it works fine for one day and everything is fast and responsive, but after a day or two it stops working.

Specs:

RAM: 8GB
  SSD: 256 GB
  Processor: Intel Xeon W3550 4x 3.06GHz
  Graphics card: Nvidia GT730 4GB
  Ubuntu version: 22.04

Comment: It may help if you clarify some details; you've tagged this question is about Ubuntu 14.04 LTS & Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?  How does 14.04 relate?  You've also not said if you've installed the Server or Desktop ISO.  Did you look at any logs for clues? If it works well post-install, but ceases too after a few days; were changes made??  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS being a LTS has kernel stack choice; 22.04.3 will install with a 5.15 or 6.2 kernel (*depending on unstated install media*) and remain on 5.15 or update to 6.5 (*if 6.2 was installed*) so is the *slowness* related to that update? for example.

Comment: sorry for confusion in my question actually this is my first time asking a question on any forum.
As far as kernal version is considered it was 6.2 earlier at installation time now after update it is 6.5.0-14-generic

Comment: Depending on which Ubuntu 22.04 system you install (*you only give release details; ie. 22.04, and not what product, eg. Server, Desktop etc*) the GA kernel stack is installed (ie. 5.15 that will remain 5.15), or HWE (*which will update; 22.04.3 used 6.2 kernel, with .4 upgrades rolling out now meaning it'll change to 6.5 kernel*) so that's expected. This is a Q&A site, and whilst like a forum, not the same. If providing extra details; you should add that to your question, as the question is what is answered (comments being from readers to the OP/Original Poster,& removed once addressed).

Comment: Have you updated firmware, both UEFI & SSDs? Compare to vendors support page: `sudo lshw | grep -m 1 -A 5 "*-firmware"` & `udisksctl status`  Some things to review & possible setting changes: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster Often boot that slow is timeout on missing mounts in fstab.