# Boot into Ubuntu takes forever when HDD is connected

Tags: boot, dual-boot, debugging

Have a dual-boot system (Ubuntu 22.04 and Win10) running on a Lenovo Thinkpad.

No issues with either until last week when booting into Ubuntu partition started to take ~10-15mins from typical 60s.

Was able to troubleshoot and identify that the issue arises when one of my 3 external HDs is connected to the laptop.  Not seeing anything in `/var/log/syslog`, and have included output from the debugging commands I've seen mentioned.  Not sure how useful as I removed the problem-causing HD to get into the system:

```
chris@chris-X1C6:~$ systemd-analyze blame
1min 40.340s fstrim.service
     40.929s apt-daily-upgrade.service
     26.476s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     13.852s apt-daily.service
      6.576s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      5.565s gpu-manager.service
      5.252s plexmediaserver.service
      4.819s plocate-updatedb.service
      4.160s qemu-kvm.service
      2.784s snapd.service
      1.846s fwupd.service
      1.436s systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
      1.274s mysql.service
       731ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-0c2e04fe\x2d9691\x2d4db4\x2da0c1\x2dabc269f2460c.service


chris@chris-X1C6:~$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @29.201s
└─multi-user.target @29.201s
  └─plymouth-quit-wait.service @2.723s +26.476s
    └─systemd-user-sessions.service @2.695s +14ms
      └─network.target @2.643s
        └─NetworkManager.service @2.269s +364ms
          └─dbus.service @2.264s
            └─basic.target @2.255s
              └─sockets.target @2.255s
                └─snapd.socket @2.237s +17ms
                  └─sysinit.target @2.231s
                    └─systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service @6.069s +1.436s
                      └─system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice @1.287s
                        └─system.slice @290ms
                          └─-.slice @290ms
```

Comment: Do you have NTFS partitions that are hibernated or need chkdsk or ext4 partition(s) that need fsck? Some settings you can change, still apply for newer versions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Comment: @oldfred, the offending drive is formatted as ext4; have a shared partition on laptop HD formatted as NTFS and two other external HDs as NTFS as well (to share btwn Win and Linux)