【24.04】How to show systemd log on boot
I found when Ubuntu 24.04 is booting and showing Ubuntu logo,I cannot press anykey to show the logcat of systemd like 22.04.But sometimes I need this to read the logcat in time.Could I restore this function?Thanks!

One of the settings I still use to speed up boot. Is in grub change quiet,splash to noplymouth.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster
