My First M.2 Drive Boot Issues
I'm using a 2TB WD Black SN770 NVMe SSD on an MSI MAG Tomahawk B550 mobo. The system boots, but it takes way too long  (approx. 3 minutes) and it will NOT reboot from the $ reboot command nor from the hardware reset button on the computer;  no video either way.
When I turn power off and back on, I get the Kubuntu boot screen
*Kubuntu 
Kubuntu Advanced Options
Kubuntu safe recovery

remaining lines from the standard menu
I select the 1st or 2nd line (generic kernel) and wait because the next screen looks like this:
[     0.001259] __common_interrupt: 1.55 No irq handler for vector

[     0.001259] __common_interrupt: 2.55 No irq handler for vector

[     0.001259] __common_interrupt: 3.55 No irq handler for vector
 
[     0.001259] __common_interrupt: 4.55 No irq handler for vector

[     0.001259] __common_interrupt: 5.55 No irq handler for vector

[     0.001259] __common_interrupt: 6.55 No irq handler for vector

[     0.001259] __common_interrupt: 7.55 No irq handler for vector

[     0.001259] __common_interrupt: 8.55 No irq handler for vector

[     0.001259] __common_interrupt: 9.55 No irq handler for vector

[     0.001259] __common_interrupt: 10.55 No irq handler for vector

That stays on the monitor for about 3 minutes then my system boots up with the following issues:
Default wallpaper; the one I setup is gone. All the other settings are I modified are good.
I was under the impression that NVMe SSDs on the PCI bus allows a system to boot considerably faster so I'm thinking this is something that can be fixed.  Please advise.

Have you updated UEFI firmware? And even a new NVMe drive may have firmware updates, best to check. sudo dmidecode -s bios-version &
udisksctl status Compare to vendor's support site. You can tune settings also. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster I have used same settings on Kubuntu 22.04 & 24.04.

I didn't know that NVMe drives have firmware that can be updated.  I DL'd new BIOS for my mobo that just came out in March so I'm hopeful.

Flashing the mobo BIOS solved this issue.  Thank you.  How do I edit the question title to add the work (SOLVED)?

With AskUbuntu, you post an answer. You can post exactly what you did and a day later accept that answer, so others will know it is a good solution.

I corrected the issue by updating the mobo BIOS.  It was released in March of this year so it's the latest and greatest. No my system boots in about 30 seconds with no grub menu or irq handling errors.
Thank you all for reading and commenting on my post.
