Help me troubleshoot slow boot since 24.04 upgrade
As stated in title, this is since 24.04 upgrade.
Before the upgrade, total boot from POST to desktop manager was around 15-20 seconds. It is now 70-80 seconds from POST.
Here are some outputs that I hope may help. I've seen them in numerous troubleshooting posts but I'm not sure how to interpret them.
EDIT: After removing snapd boot time is unchanged. I noticed that in systemd-analyze critical-chain, NetworkManager seems to be the one adding 1m though, but I don't know where to go from there.
Also, I don't know why systemd-analyze blame is double the length after removing snapd and editing my post but it's not an issue imho as 95% of it reports it loads in 600ms.
Thanks for your help !
dmesg (truncated to show the gap in the boot time) :
[    6.239394] loop5: detected capacity change from 0 to 8
[    6.829137] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input25
[    6.829175] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input26
[    6.829206] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input27
[    6.829237] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input28
[   25.714347] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:1028.0005: HID++ 1.0 device connected.
[   66.330236] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Registered PHC clock: iwlwifi-PTP, with index: 1
[   69.431049] wlo1: authenticate with 54:b8:0a:09:1e:64 (local address=98:3b:8f:e4:8b:99)
[   69.432064] wlo1: send auth to 54:b8:0a:09:1e:64 (try 1/3)
[   69.488027] wlo1: authenticated
[   69.488515] wlo1: associate with 54:b8:0a:09:1e:64 (try 1/3)
[   69.513233] wlo1: RX AssocResp from 54:b8:0a:09:1e:64 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=2)
[   69.519946] wlo1: associated

systemd-analyze critical-chain
graphical.target @1min 9.070s
└─multi-user.target @1min 9.069s
  └─teamviewerd.service @1min 8.977s +92ms
    └─network-online.target @1min 8.955s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1min 3.173s +5.779s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1.830s +1min 1.341s
          └─dbus.service @1.711s +63ms
            └─basic.target @1.671s
              └─sockets.target @1.671s
                └─uuidd.socket @1.671s
                  └─sysinit.target @1.666s
                    └─systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service @1min 2.798s +12ms
                      └─system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice @1.552s
                        └─system.slice @180ms
                          └─-.slice @180ms

systemd-analyze blame
1min 1.341s NetworkManager.service
     5.779s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      694ms systemd-binfmt.service
      668ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
      639ms systemd-rfkill.service
      396ms thermald.service
      385ms apport.service
      371ms dev-nvme0n1p5.device
      220ms user@1000.service
      215ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
      211ms rsyslog.service
      204ms gnome-remote-desktop.service
      201ms udisks2.service
      200ms apparmor.service
      195ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
      191ms power-profiles-daemon.service
      188ms polkit.service
      184ms accounts-daemon.service
      182ms gpu-manager.service
      172ms systemd-resolved.service
      167ms undervolt.service
      149ms apport-autoreport.service
      134ms systemd-journal-flush.service
      133ms upower.service
      119ms avahi-daemon.service
      110ms bluetooth.service
      110ms systemd-logind.service
      109ms secureboot-db.service
       96ms grub-common.service
       92ms teamviewerd.service
       88ms lm-sensors.service
       78ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-D25E\x2dF6A4.service
       78ms ddclient.service
       76ms systemd-udevd.service
       75ms ModemManager.service
       73ms keyboard-setup.service
       71ms packagekit.service
       69ms switcheroo-control.service
       65ms systemd-journald.service
       63ms dbus.service
       58ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       53ms e2scrub_reap.service
       50ms smartmontools.service
       42ms plymouth-start.service


Which value are you saying is slow?

Some settings you can adjust. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster I use Kubuntu and no snaps. And have used same settings with 22.04 & 24.04.

@oldfred I completely removed snapd before, and it didn't change the boot time. I'm going to try again though, and update the answer without it if it still doesn't solve it.

@David in the dmesg output, you can see how it goes from 6secs to 60+, doing almost nothing in between. Just before the update the boot was 15 seconds from POST to desktop.

So, after countless more hours of debugging, I've stumbled upon a solution by deleting an old Wifi "remembered" connection, and only keeping the one I actually use. It instantly solved it.
Maybe I've failed to mention I'm on a laptop that booted without Ethernet. That was a Wifi-only situation. If that can help anyone.
